# Convert a string of binary characters to the ASCII equivalents

Tags: code-golf, string, binary

Take a string of binary characters separated by a space, and convert it to an ASCII string.

For example...

```
1001000 1100101 1101100 1101100 1101111 100000 1010111 1101111 1110010 1101100 1100100
```

Would convert to...

```
Hello World
```

**This is a code-golf challenge so the shortest solution wins.**

Comment: +1 for making a challenge without story and other fripperies, straight to the point

Comment: @bebe Fictitious fantastical fripperies form half the fun.

Comment: Hello. Let's imagine that your technology is so advanced that it does not support ASCII. Would it be allowed to convert to the native character encoding, or would it have to convert ASCII to the native character encoding? I'm thinking `ZX81` here.

Answer (score 12):

## JavaScript (ES6) 49 <s>55 56 64</s>

```
s.replace(/\d+./g,x=>String.fromCharCode('0b'+x))
```

**Edit** Accepting @bebe suggestion - thanks
**Edit2** Didn't know about binary numeric literal - thanks @kapep
**Edit3** Wow 6 <s>not 4</s> bytes saved thx @ETHproductions

**Explanation** as requested in comments

`String.replace` can take 2 arguments:

- regular expression `/\d+./g` : one or more digits followed by one different character - the g flag specify to search the pattern more than once
- a function, here specified in arrow format, where the argument (x) wil be the found string (the sequence of digits eventually followed by a space) and the value of the function is what is replaced (in this case, the single character from the code).

It's worth noting that the at the end of the string the regexp matches the sequence of digits without a trailing space, in this case the dot matches the last digit. Try '123'.match(/(\d+)./) to verify.

(Still) one of the more verbose pieces of javascript ever... 
(Assignment to string s not counted)

```js
var s='1001000 1100101 1101100 1101100 1101111 100000 1010111 1101111 1110010 1101100 1100100'
var x=
s.replace(/\d+./g,x=>String.fromCharCode('0b'+x))

console.log(x)
```

Comment: `s.replace(/\d+./g,x=>String.fromCharCode(parseInt(x,2)))` 56

Comment: `s.replace(/\d+./g,x=>String.fromCharCode(eval("0b"+x)))` 55

Comment: Can you please explain what the `/\d+./g,x=>`does?

Comment: @izlin I added some explanation to the answer

Comment: I know this is an old answer, but you can change `eval('0b'+x)` to `'0b'+x-0` to save 4 bytes.

Comment: Firstly, it's 54. Secondly,`s.split(' ').map(x=>String.fromCharCode(eval('0b'+x)))` is also 54, but it returns char array

Comment: @username.ak it's 55, count again. But it will be less an a couple of minutes

Comment: @ETHproductions great, thanks

Comment: Believe it or not, I've discovered you can actually remove the `-0`. I guess `String.fromCharCode` casts to number implicitly

Comment: @ETHproductions unbelievable. (and again 4 stroked is 4)

Answer (score 10):

## Ruby, <s>36</s> 32

```
s.split.map{|x|x.to_i(2).chr}*""
```

### Or 31

```
s.gsub(/\w+ ?/){$&.to_i(2).chr}
```

Optimizations thanks to Chron

Comment: You could substitute `.join""` for `*""` to save a few characters.  You could also do it with gsub instead of split+map+join, something like: `s.gsub(/\w+ ?/){$&.to_i(2).chr}` (31 chars).

Comment: `s.gsub(/\d+./){$&.to_i(2).chr}` works and it's 30 chars, I have no idea why it works though. The `.` shouldn't match the last time but it does.

Answer (score 8):

## Bash+common linux utils, 25 bytes

```
dc<<<2i$s[Pz0\<m]dsmx|rev
```

#### dc explanation

- push 2 to the stack; pop and use as input radix
- push input string to stack (all values at once)
- Define recursive macro `m` to:

  - pop, then print value as ASCII
  - push stack depth to stack
  - push 0 to stack
  - pop top 2 stack values; compare and call `m` macro if stack non-empty
- duplicate top of stack (macro definition)
- pop and save macro to `m` register
- pop and execute macro

Because we push the whole binary string to the stack first, when we pop each value, we end up with the string reversed.  So we use the `rev` utility to correct that.

#### Example usage:

```
$ s="1001000 1100101 1101100 1101100 1101111 100000 1010111 1101111 1110010 1101100 1100100"
$ dc<<<2i$s[Pz0\<m]dsmx|rev
Hello World
$
```

Answer (score 7):

### PowerShell, 49

```
-join(-split$s|%{[char][convert]::toint32($_,2)})
```

EDIT: Didn't see the other PowerShell answer. But there is essentially only one way of solving this.

Answer (score 7):

## C - <s>57</s> <s>43</s> 38/31

38 Byte version:

```c
for(int*x=s;putchar(strtol(x,&x,2)););
```

Or only 31 bytes if s is a pointer:

```c
while(putchar(strtol(s,&s,2)));
```

I don't think this is exactly how for and while loop are supposed to be used... but it works.

Answer (score 6):

### Mathematica, 52 bytes

Ah, Mathematica's lovely function names

```
f=FromCharacterCode[#~FromDigits~2&/@StringSplit@#]&
```

Answer (score 6):

### Powershell (<strike>52</strike> 49)

```
-join(-split$s|%{[char][convert]::ToInt16($_,2)})
```

Simple loop over binary string in $s. Having to include the [convert] kills my score though.

EDIT: There really is only one way of pulling this off in Powershell, wowie. Joey and I both got pretty much the same answer working independently!

Input:

```
1001000 1100101 1101100 1101100 1101111 100000 1010111 1101111 1110010 1101100 1100100
```

Output:

```
Hello World
```

Comment: You can use the unary split operator, saving three characters (at which point our answers are identical ... big surprise ;-)).

Comment: @Joey Ohh, good point! Can't believe I missed that. You get the +1 from me for catching that, thanks!

Answer (score 6):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 12

```
smCv+"0b"dPZ
```

Note that s is not a legal variable in Pyth, so I used Z instead.

Explanation:

```
        print(
s             sum(
m                 map(lambda d:
C                     chr(
v                         eval(
+"0b"d                         "0b"+d)),
P                     split(
Z                           Z))))
```

Example:

```
=Z"<the binary string from above>"smCv+"0b"dPZ
Hello World
```

Comment: The fact it does not use whitespace in the formatting (here's looking at you Python) is a major +1

Comment: @Pharap Yeah, one way of looking at Pyth is it's Python with all of the elements that make it take more characters removed, like whitespace, parenthesis, multi-character tokens, etc.

Comment: I don't know Pyth, but would it not save 4 characters to use `id2` in place of `v+"0b"d`? In any case, this is both unreadable and cool.

Comment: @DLosc I added that function to Pyth after this question was asked, in large part due to this question. It would be shorter with present day Pyth, but present day Pyth is not allowed for this challenge.

Comment: I see. I wondered if it might be something like that.

Comment: I really like the formatting of your Explanation section.

Answer (score 6):

### x86 machine code on DOS - 22 bytes

```
00000000  30 d2 b4 08 cd 21 2c 30  72 06 d0 e2 08 c2 eb f2  |0....!,0r.......|
00000010  b4 02 cd 21 eb ea                                 |...!..|
```

Since there are no real string variables in machine code (and in particular, no variables named "`s`") I settled for stdin as input.

NASM input:

```
    org 100h

section .text

start:
    xor dl,dl
loop:
    mov ah,8
    int 21h
    sub al,'0'
    jb print
    shl dl,1
    or dl,al
    jmp loop
print:
    mov ah,2
    int 21h
    jmp start
```

Answer (score 5):

### Perl <strike>33</strike> 32

Edit: Updated solution, 32.

```
say$s=~s/\d+ ?/chr oct"0b$&"/rge
```

Previous solution (33):

```
$_=$s;say map{chr oct"0b$_"}split
```

or

```
say map{chr oct"0b$_"}split/ /,$s
```

Test:

```
perl -E '$s="1001000 1100101 1101100 1101100 1101111 100000 1010111 1101111 1110010 1101100 1100100";$_=$s;say map{chr oct"0b$_"}split'
```

Answer (score 5):

### J (23)

```
u:;(#.@:("."0))&.>cut s
```

Test:

```
   s=:'1001000 1100101 1101100 1101100 1101111 100000 1010111 1101111 1110010 1101100 1100100'
   u:;(#.@:("."0))&.>cut s
Hello World
```

Explanation:

```
                  cut s    NB. split S on spaces
   (          )&.>         NB. for each element
        ("."0)             NB. evaluate each character
      @:                   NB. and
    #.                     NB. convert bitstring to number
  ;                        NB. unbox each number
u:                         NB. convert to ASCII
```

Answer (score 4):

### Python shell  <strike>44</strike>   40 chars

```
''.join(chr(int(x,2))for x in s.split())
```

Thanks for the help [Griffin](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/2501/griffin).

Comment: ''.join(chr(int(x,2))for x in s.split())

Answer (score 4):

## Golfscript - 21

```
' '/{1/{~}%2base}%''+
```

You can test it [here](http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=IjEwMDEwMDAgMTEwMDEwMSAxMTAxMTAwIDExMDExMDAgMTEwMTExMSAxMDAwMDAgMTAxMDExMSAxMTAxMTExIDExMTAwMTAgMTEwMTEwMCAxMTAwMTAwIgonICcvezEve359JTJiYXNlfSUnJysgcA%3D%3D).

Answer (score 4):

### APL (15)

```
⎕UCS{2⊥⍎¨⍕⍵}¨⍎s
```

Test:

```
      s←'1001000 1100101 1101100 1101100 1101111 100000 1010111 1101111 1110010 1101100 1100100'
      ⎕UCS{2⊥⍎¨⍕⍵}¨⍎s
Hello World
```

Explanation:

- `⍎s`: evaluate `s`, turning it into an array of integers. Arrays are written as numbers separated by spaces, so this splits `s`.
- `{`...`}¨`: for each element:

  - `⍕⍵`: turn the number back into a string
  - `⍎¨`: evaluate each individual digit, giving a bitstring
  - `2⊥`: base-2 decode, giving the numbers
- `⎕UCS`: get the character for each number

Comment: Unless otherwise specified you should count bytes instead of characters: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/code-golf/info :)

Comment: @Averroes: the APL charset fits in a byte with room to spare: http://frankenstein.d-n-s.org.uk/~marinus/aplcharset.png

Comment: Ah, I didn't know it. My bad. Sorry!

Answer (score 4):

## PHP (61)

```
<?=join(array_map('chr',array_map('bindec',explode(' ',$s))))
```

Comment: `foreach(str_split($s,8)as$v)echo chr(bindec($v));`

Comment: @JörgHülsermann the encoding may skip leading zeros therefore `str_split($s,8)` won't work. `foreach(explode(' ',$s)as$v)echo chr(bindec($v));` would be valid but I don't plan to edit one of my first PPGC answers that clearly isn't really golfed anyway. Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 4):

### [Bacchus](https://sites.google.com/site/bacchuslanguage/), 25 bytes

```
S,' 'j:A=(Ö,2,10b:c),A¨
```

Explanation:

`S,' 'j` split the String S by the empty space and converts it to a block (some sort of array).

`:A=` get the previous Block and assing it to A variable.

`(),A¨` for Each element in A

`Ö,2,10b` Read the current element (represent by `Ö`) in base 2 and transform it to base 10.

`:c` get the previous value and print as char

Answer (score 3):

### GolfScript 23

```
' '/{[{49=}/]2base}%''+
```

Online test [here](http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=OycxMDAxMDAwIDExMDAxMDEgMTEwMTEwMCAxMTAxMTAwIDExMDExMTEgMTAwMDAwIDEwMTAxMTEgMTEwMTExMSAxMTEwMDEwIDExMDExMDAgMTEwMDEwMCcKCicgJy97W3s0OT19L10yYmFzZX0lJycrCg%3D%3D&run=true).

Answer (score 3):

## C - 63

since C has no base 2 converter in standard library: [test here](http://codepad.org/gS0u5sN3)

edit: there is, i'm just too stupid to know about it

```
r;f(char*s){for(;*s;(*s|32)-32||(putchar(r),r=0))r=2*r|*s++&1;}
```

Answer (score 3):

## Run Length Encoded Brainfuck, 49 bytes

Since there are no variables in Brainfuck, I just used standard input and output instead.

The code `32+` should be interpreted as 32 `+`s by the interpreter. Just replace them manually if your interpreter doesn't support RLE.

```
>,[32->+<[16-<[>++<-]>[<+>-]>-<]>[<<.[-]>>-]<,]<.
```

Expanded (non-RLE) version: (91 bytes)

```
>,[-------------------------------->+<[----------------<[>++<-]>[<+>-]>-<]>[<<.[-]>>-]<,]<.
```

The code assumes that EOF is encoded as 0.

### Explanation

The following layout is used:

```
+---+---+------+
| x | a | flag |
+---+---+------+
```

Where `x` is the ASCII byte to be printed, `a` is the a character from standard input and `flag` is 1 if `a` was a space.

```
>,            Read a character a into the second cell
[             While not EOF: 
  32-           Decrease a by 32 (a -= ' ')
  >+<           Set the flag to 1 
  [             If a was not a space:
    16-           Decrease by 16 more ('0' == 32+16)
    <[>++<-]      a += 2*x
    >[<+>-]       Move it back (x = a)
    >-<           Reset the flag, it was not a space.
  ]>
  [             If a was a space (flag == 1):
    <<.[-]        Print and reset x
    >>-           Reset the flag
  ]
  <,            Read the next caracter a
]
<.            Print the last character x
```

Comment: +1 Because everything should have a brainfuck implementation.

Comment: Is "Run Length Encoded Brainfuck" an actual separate language? I can't find an interpreter.

Answer (score 3):

## Java 8 : 60 bytes

Using lambdas in Java 8 (75 bytes):

```
Arrays.stream(s.split(" ")).reduce("",(a,b)->a+(char)Byte.parseByte(b,2));
```

And if you allow static imports (which some here used) it is (61 bytes):

```java
stream(s.split(" ")).reduce("",(a,b)->a+(char)parseInt(b,2))
```

A tiny bit shorter version using for loop (60 bytes):

```java
for(String n:s.split(" ")){out.print((char)parseInt(n,2));}
```

Comment: What, they actually made a replacement for the monstrosity known as anonymous class? Awesome.

Comment: @Sieg yes Java has lambdas/closures now as well, but it is mostly synthetic sugar on top of anonymous classes... (obviously)

Answer (score 3):

## Clojure 63 (or 57)

The all-Clojure impl:

```
(apply str(map #(char(read-string(str"2r"%)))(re-seq #"\d+"s)))
```

With Java interop:

```
(apply str(map #(char(Long/parseLong % 2))(.split s" ")))
```

REPL session:

```
golf> (def s "1001000 1100101 1101100 1101100 1101111 100000 1010111 1101111 1110010 1101100 1100100")
#'golf/s
golf> (apply str(map #(char(read-string(str"2r"%)))(re-seq #"\d+"s)))
"Hello World"
golf> (apply str(map #(char(Long/parseLong % 2))(.split s" ")))
"Hello World"
```

Answer (score 3):

## QBasic, 103

```
s$=s$+" ":FOR i=1 TO LEN(s$):c$=MID$(s$,i,1):IF c$=" "THEN n=0:r$=r$+CHR$(n)ELSE n=n*2+VAL(c$)
NEXT:?r$
```

What? We have no fancy binary-to-decimal functions here. Do it yourself!

I'm counting the newline (which I think is necessary to get the if-then-else without an `END IF`) as one byte, per [this meta post](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/168/16766). I don't know whether QB64 on Windows would accept a code file that way or not. Probably doesn't much matter.

Answer (score 2):

## Haskell -- 48 (+13 imports (?))

Here's my first golf attempt in Haskell.

```haskell
map(chr.foldl1((+).(*2)).map digitToInt)$words s
```

You need to import Data.Char

usage (in ghci):

```haskell
Prelude> :m +Data.Char
Prelude Data.Char> let s = "1001000 1100101 1101100 1101100 1101111 100000 1010111 1101111 1110010 1101100 1100100"
Prelude Data.Char> map(chr.foldl1((+).(*2)).map digitToInt)$words s
"Hello World"
```

Explanation:

```haskell
map(chr.foldl1((+).(*2)).map digitToInt)$words s
                                        $words s -- split s on spaces into a list
                         map digitToInt          -- convert each digit in input string to int
              ((+).(*2))                         -- a function that multiplies its first 
-- argument by 2, then adds the second argument
        foldl1((+).(*2)).map digitToInt          -- fold the above over the list of ints: 
-- in other words this is a function that reads strings as binary and gives the value as int
   (chr.foldl1((+).(*2)).map digitToInt)         -- cast to character
map(chr.foldl1((+).(*2)).map digitToInt)$words s -- map our function over the list of words
```

Comment: Hopefully I've followed scoring conventions correctly regarding imports.  Feel free to edit in a correction if I haven't.  I treated the ":m +Data.Char" needed to import in ghci as 13.

Answer (score 2):

**NodeJS** – **62**

```
Buffer(s.split(' ').map(function(a){return parseInt(a,2)}))+''
```

**PHP** – **75**

```
array_reduce(explode(' ', $b),function($a,$b){return $a.chr(bindec($b));});
```

Comment: how do you run nodejs with es6 compatibility? the latest one still does not support lambda functions for me

Comment: @bebe Arrow functions are implemented in v8 but they aren't integrated with node yet. I'll edit my post.

Comment: @c.P.u1 they work for me

Comment: [-16 bytes suggested by an anonymous user](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/59812)

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript 111

This does the number conversion without parseInt or eval.  Reading the string backwards and counting bits it set's bit x if it's a one. When a space is found a the number is converted to a char and a new 0 number is started for setting bits.

```
x=n=0,w='',s=' '+s
for(i=s.length;i--;){m=s[i]
if(m==1)n|=1<<x
x++
if(m==' ')w=String.fromCharCode(n)+w,n=x=0
}
```

Comment: +1 for doing it the old-fashioned way--inspired me to write a QBasic version, too.

Comment: Invalid, needs to be a function or full program (one that takes input)

Answer (score 2):

## Groovy 64

```
{it.split(" ").collect{Integer.parseInt(it,2) as char}.join("")}
```

Answer (score 2):

## CJam, 11 bytes

```
NS/{:~2bc}/
```

**s** isn't a legal variable name in CJam, so I chose **N** instead.

[Try it online.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/)

#### Example run

```
$ cjam <(echo '
> "1001000 1100101 1101100 1101100 1101111 100000 1010111 1101111 1110010 1101100 1100100"
> :N;
> NS/{:~2bc}/
> '); echo
Hello World
```

#### How it works

```
NS/            " Split N at spaces.                            ";
   {     }/    " For each chunk:                               ";
    :~         "   Evaluate each character ('0' ↦ 0, '1' ↦ 1). ";
      2b       "   Convert from base 2 array to integer.       ";
        c      "   Cast to character.                          ";
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), <s>27 26</s> 22 bytes

*-1 from roblogic, -4 from a new strategy using an array and `${a/b/c}` replacement.*

```
printf %s ${(#)@/#/2#}
```

<s>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@J@moVn9Py2/SCGZKzU5I19BpVpDWdNK1yhGWSW5NiYm@X8tF1eagqGBARAZKBiCGYYgGsREpQ0NQerAygzAfIQwRB@ycpB5//8DAA)
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@J@moVn9Py2/SCGZq6AoM68kTUGlWkNZ00rXKEZZJbn2fy0XV5qCoYEBEBkoGIIZhiAaxESlDQ1B6sDKDMB8hDBEH7JykHn//wMA)</s>
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@J@moVn9v6AoM68kTUG1WEGlWkNZ00FfWd9IufZ/LRdXmoKhgQEQGSgYghmGIBrERKUNDUHqwMoMwHyEMEQfsnKQef//AwA)

The `(#)` flag causes arithmetic expansion to be done to the contents of the parameter. Flags are parsed *after* the replacement. `#` matches the start of a string when at the start of a `${ / / }` pattern. So each parameter is `#` prefixed with `2#`, which Zsh recognizes as a base 2 number when `(#)` arithmetic expansion is done.

---

This relies on flexible I/O, each group of bits in its own parameter. This is what the pure bash answer does as well. To parse a single string, **+4 bytes** are needed: ([Example](https://tio.run/##qyrO@J@moVn9Py2/SCGZKzU5I19BpVpDWdNK1yhGWSW5NiYm@X8tF1eagqGBARAZKBiCGYYgGsREpQ0NQerAygzAfIQwRB@ycpB5//8DAA))

```
printf %s ${(#)${=1}/#/2#}
```

Comment: use `printf` and you dont need to append `\\c`, saving 1 byte

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `s`, 3 bytes

```
vBC
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJzIiwiIiwidkJDIiwiIiwiW1wiMTAwMTAwMFwiLFwiMTEwMDEwMVwiLFwiMTEwMTEwMFwiLFwiMTEwMTEwMFwiLFwiMTEwMTExMVwiLFwiMTAwMDAwXCIsXCIxMDEwMTExXCIsXCIxMTAxMTExXCIsXCIxMTEwMDEwXCIsXCIxMTAxMTAwXCIsXCIxMTAwMTAwXCJdIl0=)

### How?

```
vBC
vB   # Vectorized convert to decimal
  C  # Convert character codes to list of characters
     # S flag concatenates result
```

### If we *have* to receive input separated by spaces, then:

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `s`, 4 bytes

```
⌈vBC
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJzIiwiIiwi4oyIdkJDIiwiIiwiMTAwMTAwMCAxMTAwMTAxIDExMDExMDAgMTEwMTEwMCAxMTAxMTExIDEwMDAwMCAxMDEwMTExIDExMDExMTEgMTExMDAxMCAxMTAxMTAwIDExMDAxMDAiXQ==)

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 4 bytes

Saved 3 bytes thanks to @Emigna

```
#CçJ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@6/sfHi51///hgYGQGSggEYDAA)

Comment: `#CçJ` also works. Although in both this and your version you need `ð¡` instead of `#` if the input can be only 1 char.

Answer (score 1):

## GNU Sed, 19 bytes

Inspired by an [excellent](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/35119/61904) @Digital Trauma answer.

**Golfed**

```
s/\w*/dc -e2i&P;/eg
```

**Test**

```
echo 1001000 1100101 1101100 1101100 1101111 100000 1010111 1101111 1110010 1101100 1100100|\
sed 's/\w*/dc -e2i&P;/eg'

Hello World
```

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth, 7 bytes

```
smCid2c
```

Takes input as string.

[Try it!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=smCid2c&input=%2201100001+01100010+01100011%22&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%2201100001+01100010+01100011%22%0A%2201010100+01100101+01110011+01110100%22%0A%2201001000+01100101+01101100+01101100+01101111%22%0A%2201010111+01101111+01110010+01101100+01100100+00001101+00001010%22%0A%2201000101+01111000+01100001+01101101+01110000+01101100+01100101+00001101+00001010%22%0A%2201100010+01101001+01101110+00001101+00001010%22&debug=0)

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E (legacy)](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/tree/fb4a2ce2bce6660e1a680a74dd61b72c945e6c3b), 4 bytes

```
#CçJ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f9f2fnwcq///w0NDIDIQMEQzDAE0SAmKm0IFDcwACszAPMRwhB9yMpB5gEA)

### Explanation:

```
#CçJ
#   : Split implicit input at spaces
 C  : Convert every element to int
  ç : chr(n)
   J: Join elements, push it to the stack for printing
```

**Edit:** I noticed I perfectly duplicated a previous answer by my own, but keep it.

Comment: Because the language is newer than the question

Comment: That's [ok](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12877/lets-allow-newer-languages-versions-for-older-challenges).  No need to mark it as non-competing.

Comment: Okay. Thanks! Removed

Answer (score 1):

## [K4](https://kx.com/download/), 18 bytes

**Solution:**

```
"c"$2/:'"1"=" "\:s
```

**Example:**

```
q)s:"1001000 1100101 1101100 1101100 1101111 100000 1010111 1101111 1110010 1101100 1100100"
q)k)"c"$2/:'"1"=" "\:s
"Hello World"
```

**Explanation:**

```
"c"$2/:'"1"=" "\:s / the solution
                 s / the input
            " "\:  / split (\:) on " "
        "1"=       / equal to "1" ?
    2/:'           / join (/:) each (') from base-2
"c"$               / cast to characters
```

Answer (score 1):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://gitlab.com/n9n/k), <s>15</s> 11 bytes

**Solution:**

```
`c$2/10\. s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNS8/7X2ylZGhgAEQGCoZghiGIBjFRaUOguIEBWJkBmI8QhuhDVg4yT@l/QrKKkb6hQYyeQvH//wA)

**Explanation:**

```
`c$2/10\. s / the solution
          s / input s
        .   / value "1100" => 1100
     10\    / convert to base 10
   2/       / convert from base 2
`c$         / cast to character
```

- **-4 bytes** thanks to ngn!

Comment: it's shorter if you evaluate `s` as is, encode it in decimal, and decode it from binary: [`\`c$2/10\. s`](https://tio.run/##y9bNS8/7X2ylZGhgAEQGCoZghiGIBjFRaUOguIEBWJkBmI8QhuhDVg4yT@l/QrKKkb6hQYyeQvH//wA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 33 bytes

```python
bytes(int(c,2)for c in s.split())
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZpuTmJuUkqhQbBXzP6myJLVYIzOvRCNZx0gzLb9IIVkhM0@hWK@4ICezRENT839BEUg2TUPJ0MAAiAwUDMEMQxANYqLShkBxAwOwMgMwHyEM0YesHGSeEtAKAA)

This solution outputs a byte string in Python. If it is required to return a regular Python string:

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 42 bytes

```python
bytes(int(c,2)for c in s.split()).decode()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZpuTmJuUkqhQbBXzP6myJLVYIzOvRCNZx0gzLb9IIVkhM0@hWK@4ICezRENTUy8lNTk/JVVD839BEUhZmoaSoYEBEBkoGIIZhiAaxESlDYHiBgZgZQZgPkIYog9ZOcg8JU3N/wA)

Answer (score 1):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), <s>74</s> 61 bytes

```
,[>++++[>++++<-]>[<+<-->>-]<<[>[<->-]<<[>++<-]]<[.[-]]>>>,]<.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VUxLCoBACL1K@8ZB9@JFxEUFQQQtgs5vjhNUIr6PT@dz2o71Wnb3ojJG9clgohwAImDMGgoelltjrRogIsW4uhNiNA6UhBo2@kcKHzFjmPq1@9033v7d)

**Explanation:**

```
[tape: char, 'input, 16, 16]
[      else]

,[                      for each input
  >++++[>++++<-]>           set const 16
  [<+<-->>-]                decrement input by 32
  <<[                       if not input = space
    >[<->-]                     decrement input by 16
    <<[>++<-]                   add double of char to input
  ]
  <[                        else
    .                           print character
    [-]                         delete character
  ]
  >>>,                      input next character
]
<.                      print last character
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3, 43 bytes

```
for i in s.split():print(end=chr(int(i,2)))
```

fixed a blunder! Thanks to @caird-coinheringaahing XD

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/5fbKtkaGAARAYKhmCGIYgGMVFpQ6C4gQFYmQGYjxCG6ENWDjJP6X9afpFCpkJmnkKxXnFBTmaJhqZVQVFmXolGal6KbXJGkQaInaljpKmp@f8/AA)

Comment: The question says the binary string will be stored in a variable called s?

Comment: @JoKing Have you read the challenge? OP's code doesn't work ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/5fbKtkaGAARAYKhmCGIYgGMVFpQ6C4gQFYmQGYjxCG6ENWDjJP6X9afpFCpkJmnkKxXnFBTmaJhqZVQVFmXokGGOsYaWr@/w8A "Python 3 – Try It Online")), but not because of the reason you've stated. However [this](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/5fbKtkaGAARAYKhmCGIYgGMVFpQ6C4gQFYmQGYjxCG6ENWDjJP6X9afpFCpkJmnkKxXnFBTmaJhqZVQVFmXolGal6KbXJGkQaInaljpKmp@f8/AA) does work

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-a`, 24 bytes

```perl
say map chr oct"0b$_",@F
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/784sVIhN7FAITmjSCE/uUTJIEklXknHwe3/f0MDAyAyUDAEMwxBNIiJShsCxQ0MwMoMwHyEMEQfsnKQef/yC0oy8/OK/@v6muoBBf7rJgIA)

Comment: Nice one! Came up with similar but abusing ``$\`` for 22: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18lxlZJyVol3jY5o0ghP7lEySBJJV7p/39DAwMgMlAwBDMMQTSIiUobAsUNDMDKDMB8hDBEH7JykHn/8gtKMvPziv/rFhiYGOQAAA "Perl 5 – Try It Online")

Comment: Definitely a shame that the binary isn't 0-padded, could be 17 bytes :/ [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l3rYgMTlbScPJQlNLScfB7f9/A0MDEDJQMDAEswzBDBAbnWEIlAIrBYsYgIWQpAwh@lF1gdT/yy8oyczPK/6vW5AIAA "Perl 5 – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 10 bytes

```
C*FB*(a^s)
```

Sadly can't use the `-s` flag here.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P/fWcvNSUsjMa5Y8////4YGBkBkoGAIZhiCaBATlTYEihsYgJUZgPkIYYg@ZOUg8wA)

Answer (score 1):

## Scala 2.12, 47 bytes

```scala
_ split " "map(_./:(0)(_*2+_-48)toChar)mkString
```

[Try it online!](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/qpYw8MpTTX6UZRRWeQsfjQ)

Splits on spaces, maps each string representing a binary number to an integer, turns into a `Char`, and then joins all those characters together. Scala 2.12 is required because of postfix operators.

Answer (score 1):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 32 bytes

```
{&a.@#.@(-&48)@(a.&i.);._2@,&' '
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/q9US9RyU9Rw0dNVMLDQdNBL11DL1NK314o0cdNTUFdT/a3KlJmfkK6QpqBsaGACRgYIhmGEIokFMVNoQKG5gAFZmAOYjhCH6kJWDzFP/DwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 30 bytes

```
[ " "split [ bin> ] ""map-as ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VU4xDsIwENv7Cut20GUFiRWxsCCmqsMRHRCRpiEJ7w9tGADJkn2Wbd1VbJlSPZ8Ox/0GOXpXigs3jFLu6ygpa0LW50uD1Qw34aEpqMe268gwz2CYJszCi/xnM/vMLcbt/tqf3m982aPag0DtFfS4uLDDAKJR4koyhmrFe8TkQqlv)

Answer (score 1):

## Excel Insider Beta v2203+, 41 Bytes

Worksheet function that takes input from range `A1` and outputs to the calling cell.

Makes use of the [`TextSplit(...)`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/textsplit-function-b1ca414e-4c21-4ca0-b1b7-bdecace8a6e7) function, one of many [text and array functions](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/excel-blog/announcing-new-text-and-array-functions/ba-p/3186066) added in Excel Insider Beta Version 2203.

```vb
=Concat(Char(Bin2Dec(TextSplit(A1," "))))
```

Answer (score 0):

## Lua, 59 bytes

```
for k in s:gmatch'%d+'do io.write(s.char(tonumber(k,2)))end
```

Comment: To convert to a string rather than write to stdout: `s:gsub('[10]+ ?',function(b)return s.char(tonumber(b,2))end)`.

Answer (score 0):

## Erlang, 45 Bytes

```
[binary_to_integer(X,2)||X<-re:split(S," ")].
```

Strings are represented as a list of integers in Erlang. This returns a list of ASCII codes which, when printed, will be represented as a string if all ASCII codes are printable characters.

Answer (score 0):

## REXX, 56 bytes (or 15)

```
o=
do w=1 to words(s)
  o=o||x2c(b2x(word(s,w)))
  end
say o
```

Alternatively, if the input values are an even 8 bits instead of varying in length as in the example, this may be shortened to just one line:

```
say x2c(b2x(s))
```

Answer (score 0):

## [AHK](https://autohotkey.com/), 115 bytes

```
Loop,Parse,s," "
{x:=D(A_LoopField)
Send % Chr(x)
}
D(x){
Return (StrLen(x)>1?D(SubStr(x,1,-1))<<1:0)|SubStr(x,0)
}
```

The loop parses the string using a space as the delimeter.
The function `D(x)` converts `x` from binary to decimal.
The `Chr` function returns the ASCII character with the value `x`.

Answer (score 0):

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 46 bytes

```
proc B s {binary f B* [regsub -all " " $s ""]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0nO@f@/oCg/WcFJoVihOikzL7GoUiFNwUlLIbooNb24NElBNzEnR0EJCFWKFZSUYmv/F5SWFCtEOykoGRgagJCBgoEhmGUIZoDY6AxDoBRYKUQELIQkZQjRj6oLpF4p9j8A)

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 51 bytes

```
proc B s {binary format B* [regsub -all " " $s ""]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XYtNCoAgFISvMjxaBYHvCl4jWlhUBJaitojo7Ka2qZhZfMxPGHSM1pkBEh5nv2zKHZiMW1WArNG6cfZ7j0ZpDUqqPIi6K9o9eLQSJFhkCwguxAUy/4FTVaZPUqJXxc//@8p76uIN)

Comment: Same byte count: https://tio.run/##XYtNCoAgFISvMkirVr4reI1qYUIh9CNqi5DO/krdVDCLj/lmolmYnd8NFALSaDftT0xQLboQvd1mrNoh9YAQF5owXOyOGNApCEkyR0JSISqQ@Q/0qDKtTaleiur/@8p7MfAN

Answer (score 0):

## q/kdb+, 22 bytes

**Solution:**

```
10h$0b sv'"1"=-8$" "vs
```

**Example:**

```
q)10h$0b sv'"1"=-8$" "vs"1001000 1100101 1101100 1101100 1101111 100000 1010111 1101111 1110010 1101100 1100100"
"Hello World"
```

**Explanation:**

Split string on `" "`, left-pad each to 8 characters, return boolean list where each string is equal to `"1"`, convert each 8-bit list to a byte and then cast to a string:

```
10h$0b sv'"1"=-8$" "vs / the solution
                 " "vs / split (vs) on " "
              -8$      / pad ($) to 8-long, negative means left-pad
          "1"=         / is item in each list equal to 1, returns true (1) or false (0) for each
    0b sv'             / convert each (') from boolean list to bytes
10h$                   / cast ($) to character type (10h)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Deorst](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/Deorst), 11 bytes

```
o k`]mxmcE;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0nNLyou@f8/XyE7ITa3IjfZ1fr///@GBgZAZKBgCGYYgmgQE5U2BIobGICVGYD5CGGIPmTlIPMA)

### How it works

Example input: `1001000 1100101`

```
o<space>    - Push a  space;    STACK = [' ', '1001000 1100101']
  k         - Turn off sort;    STACK = [' ', '1001000 1100101']
   `        - Split;            STACK = [['1001000', '1100101']]
    ]       - Flatten;          STACK = ['1001000', '1100101']
     mx     - Map from binary;  STACK = [72, 101]
       mc   - Map to character; STACK = ['H', 'e']
         E; - Concatenate;      STACK = ['H', 'e', 'He']
```

Answer (score 0):

## Perl, 27 bytes

```
say pack"(B8)*",split' ',$s
```

Comment: Doesn't work. Note that each character is a group of 7 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 40 bytes

```julia
join(Char.(parse.(Int,split(s),base=2)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VUzLCoAgELz3FdFpFyJ2u3vq1GcYBBli4hr495Z2qGBgHszMflqjOWVRHRPdoJar4MJF/pnvnKjWqPo3fnbfevnrmtSqvB/GwbTpMIDXQdYBZhd78dZEEOwXLasaETH7YFy0DhLmCw)

Answer (score 0):

## [Gol><>](https://github.com/Sp3000/Golfish), <s>27</s> 24 bytes

```
IWaSD$|rlF2LX*}|lR+oiE;~
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PScsszvj/3zM8MdhFpaYox83IJ0KrtiYnSDs/09W67v9/QwMDIDJQMAQzDEE0iIlKGwLFDQzAygzAfIQwRB@ycpB5AA)

Explanation:

```
I                         //Read the next number as integer
 W                        //Loop to extract single digits
  aSD                     //  Perform a mod & div by 10 on the current number
     $|                   //  Repeat until the number is 0
       r                  //Reverse the stack to go from LSB to MSB
        lF                //Loop over all single bits and replace all 1's with their corresponding value
          2LX             //  Push 2^x where x is the number of the current bit -> value of topmost bit
             *            //  Multiply the value of the topmost bit with the bit itself
              }|          //  Shift right to get the next bit
                lR+       //Add all values on the stack together
                   o      //Output the decimal value as a char
                    iE;~  //Check for EOF if true terminate
```

Answer (score 0):

## Common Lisp, 79 bytes

```
(map'string'code-char(let((*read-base* 2))(read-from-string(format()"(~a)"s))))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VYzBCgMhDETv/QrxssmCEPtHqavtwlolSo/9davuoW0IzJthEnfsJTfYfHixqKK0JepLyk6wQwf@q@050azR9N/4vPutj38aL5Blf7oGkfNSauf74tLmjXuwwOErwCqeN3Pj4ld1RYRpg6Rozj6EJJEroIY3oy7Yp2H7AA)

Answer (score 0):

## Powershell, 48 bytes

*Inspired by [Joey's](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/35135/80745) and [fuandon's](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/35110/80745) answers.*

```powershell
-join(-split$s|%{[char][convert]::ToByte($_,2)})
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 24 bytes

```perl6
*.words>>.&{:2($_)}.chrs
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPtfS688vyil2M5OT63aykhDJV6zVi85o6j4vzVXcWKlQpqGkqGBARAZKBiCGYYgGsREpQ2B4gYGYGUGYD5CGKIPWTnIPCXN/wA)

Anonymous Whatever lambda that takes a string and returns a string.

#### Explanation

```perl6
*.words                   # Split by spaces
       >>.&{      }       # Map each word to
            :2($_)        # Parsing it as binary
                   .chrs  # Convert to characters
```

Answer (score 0):

## Bash (Pure): 54

Pure [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) **and** no fork!

```
f(){ for a;do printf -vv \\%o $[2#$a];printf $v;done;}

f 1001000 1100101 1101100 1101100 1101111 100000 1010111 1101111 1110010 1101100 1100100
Hello World
```

#### Explanation

- `f()` declare function f
- `for a;do ... done` take each argument successively and attrib them to variable `a` in loop
- `$[2#$a]` convert binary to decimal
- `printf -vv \\%o $...` convert decimal to octal, preceded by backslash `\` for next printf and attribute this to variable `v`.
- `printf $v` will render character.

Answer (score 0):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 61 bytes

```cs
s.Split(" ").Aggregate("",(a,b)=>a+(char)Convert.ToByte(b,2))
```

Splits the binary string, and adds each byte into the string. You need to have the seed for aggregate, or else the first byte won't be parsed.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy7WTS7O/F@WWKRQbKtkaGAARAYKhmCGIYgGMVFpQ6C4gQFYmQGYjxCG6ENWDjJPyZorvCizJFXjf7FecEFOZomGkoKSpp5jenpRanoiUFxJSUcjUSdJ09YuUVsjOSOxSNM5P68stahELyTfqRKoIEnHSFPzv6b1fwA)

Comment: Invalid, needs to be either a full program or a function/lambda

Comment: [64](https://tio.run/##VYzBCgIhEIbvPYV4cshEu24rVNCpW0FnV1wTFjfUgp7e1D1UMPD98/PN6LjR0eXT0@tdTMF5S9FCicY@x15GdnlMLhGMMLC9tcFYlQzBmBJFB@ilWhN9VwGOs3@ZkNh1PryLMNAtQO5Wt@CSOTtvyEiw4LwMR6IFUVnjP0XpOW8ab/u3Xu5@9foPA3T5Aw)

Comment: Look at the javascript answer on the first page. It doesn't use a function. The question even says the variable is predefined.

Comment: :/ then that's invalid too

Comment: But the OP says that the the binary string is already contained in a variable named s.

Comment: Oh wait >_> didn't see that

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-P`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 4 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
¸®Íd
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LVA&code=uK7NZA&input=IjEwMDEwMDAgMTEwMDEwMSAxMTAxMTAwIDExMDExMDAgMTEwMTExMSAxMDAwMDAgMTAxMDExMSAxMTAxMTExIDExMTAwMTAgMTEwMTEwMCAxMTAwMTAwIg)

```
¸®Íd     :Implicit input of string
¸        :Split on spaces
 ®       :Map
  Í      :  Convert from binary string to integer
   d     :  Get character at that codepoint
         :Implicitly join & output
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 44 bytes

```julia
prod(Char.(parse.(Int,split(s," "),base=2)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPhfrGCroGRoYABEBgqGYIYhiAYxUWlDoLiBAViZAZiPEIboQ1YOMk@Jy6E4I79cISk1PTPvf0FRfoqGc0ZikZ5GQWJRcaqehmdeiU5xQU5miUaxjpKCkqZOUmJxqq2Rpqbm/9S8lP8A)

Answer (score 0):

## Python 3, 55 bytes

```python
lambda s:"".join(map(lambda b:chr(int(b,2)),s.split()))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PycxNyklUaHYSklJLys/M08jN7FAAyqYZJWcUaSRmVeikaRjpKmpU6xXXJCTWaKhqan5/z8A)

Or 46 bytes if we return an iterator instead of a string:

```python
lambda s:map(lambda b:chr(int(b,2)),s.split())
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PycxNyklUaHYKjexQAPKSbJKzijSyMwr0UjSMdLU1CnWKy7IySzR0NT8/x8A)

Answer (score 0):

## TECO, 35 bytes

```
Z+1<0A"DQn*2#(0A-48)Un|QnI^[0Un'1:D>
```

`^[` stands for <kbd>esc</kbd>.

### Explanation

```
I1001000 1100101 1101100 1101100 1101111 100000 1010111 1101111 1110010 1101100 1100100^[
! insert input string to the buffer !
J     ! reset to zero point !
Z+1<  ! loop over all chars !
0A"D  ! if the current char is a digit !
Qn*2#(0A-48)Un ! append the bit to register n !
D     ! remove current char !
|     ! else !
QnI^[ ! insert value of register n as ASCII !
0Un   ! clear n !
1:D   ! delete one char without signaling error !
'     ! end if !
>     ! end loop !
HT    ! type out result !
```

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript, 64 bytes

```javascript
s=>s.replace(/\d+./g,c=>eval(`'\\x${('0b'+c|0).toString(16)}'`))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VUy9CsMgGNzzFB0KKknN59IlmJfo6hBrjKSIBpVQaPvsNqZDWzi4H@7uJlcZVZiXdHJ@1HniOfI@0qAXK5XGrRhr2ppG8V6v0uIBCXE/PjCCK6rVEwhN/pLC7AxmZ/JCAyG5qyrlXfRWU@sNnjBiABvgwHbBChf5z2zLAfYa7P4bf3a/9fKHCOnyGw)

Trying something different to [this JS answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/35129/87728), not sure if it can be shorter.

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <strike>48</strike> 44 bytes

```python
[print(end=chr(int(i,2)))for i in s.split()]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/5fbKtkaGAARAYKhmCGIYgGMVFpQ6C4gQFYmQGYjxCG6ENWDjJP6X90QVFmXolGal6KbXJGkQaInaljpKmpmZZfpJCpkJmnUKxXXJCTWaKhGfv/PwA)

previous answer,

```python
[print(end=chr(eval('0b'+i)))for i in s.split()]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/5fbKtkaGAARAYKhmCGIYgGMVFpQ6C4gQFYmQGYjxCG6ENWDjJP6X90QVFmXolGal6KbXJGkUZqWWKOhrpBkrp2pqamZlp@kUKmQmaeQrFecUFOZomGZuz//wA)

Learnt the `print(end=...)` trick in the "Scream the loudest" challenge. Pretty neat.

As far as I know, there is no direct conversion to ascii from binary string, so we have to suffer the `'0b'` in the `eval`.

Thanks to [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/191211/106829) python answer for giving `int(i,2)`

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 53 bytes

```python
lambda x:[print(end=chr(int(i,2)))for i in x.split()]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUaHCKrqgKDOvRCM1L8U2OaNIA8TO1DHS1NRMyy9SyFTIzFOo0CsuyMks0dCM/Z@moWRoYABEBgqGYIYhiAYxUWlDoLiBAViZAZiPEIboQ1YOMk9J8z8A)

Used the `int(i,2)` to convert number from base 2 to 10. In-built functions for the win.

Answer (score 0):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 30 bytes

Nothing too fancy, but it's relatively short

```matlab
@(x)['',bin2dec(strsplit(x))']
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/Z@mYKugp6f330GjQjNaXV0nKTPPKCU1WaO4pKi4ICezBCisqR77P01D3dDAAIgMFAzBDEMQDWKi0oZAcQMDsDIDMB8hDNGHrBxknrrmfwA)

```matlab
@(x)                            % Take x as input
@(x)            strsplit(x)     % split string at spaces and create a cell array
@(x)    bin2dec(strsplit(x))    % Convert each row to integers
@(x)    bin2dec(strsplit(x))'   % Transpose into column vector
@(x)['',bin2dec(strsplit(x))']  % Concatenate with the empty string to cast to chars
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2) `J`, 3 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
OḂC
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faGm0kpdS7IKlpSVpuhZL_R_uaHJeUpyUXAwVWXAzzNDAAIgMFAzBDEMQDWKi0oZAcQMDsDIDMB8hDNGHrBxkHsR4AA)

But, if a list of strings was an allowed input format:

#### [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2) `J`, 2 bytes

```
ḂC
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faGm0kpdS7IKlpSVpuhZLHu5ocl5SnJRcDBVYcLMiWt3QwACIDNR1FNQNwWxDKBPEw8Y0hCgwMIDpMgCLostDDMM0AGSbeizEAQA)

##### Explanation

```python
OḂC  # Implicit input
O    # Split on spaces
 Ḃ   # Convert from binary
  C  # Convert to characters
     # Implicit output
```

Answer (score -1):

## Python, 46 bytes

```
''.join(map(lambda x:chr(int(x,2)),s.split()))
```