# String to Binary

Tags: code-golf, string, binary, conversion

This is a code golf challenge. Just like the title says, write a program to covert a string of ascii characters into binary.

For example:

`"Hello World!"`
should turn into 
`1001000 1100101 1101100 1101100 1101111 100000 1010111 1101111 1110010 1101100 1100100 100001`.

Note: I am particularly interested in a pyth implementation.

Comment: We had the reversed asked: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/35096/convert-a-string-of-binary-characters-to-the-ascii-equivalents

Comment: I noticed that. There's an anecdote for why I asked this question. I encouraged my friend to learn programming, and he took a java class last summer where each student had to pick a project. He told me he wanted to translate text to binary, which I then did (to his dismay) in python 3 in 1 line (a very long line). I find it incredible that his project idea can be distilled down to 8 bytes.

Comment: that's cool, thanks for sharing! I do like easier questions like this because it gives more people a chance to participate and generates lots of content in the form of answers.

Comment: Can I take input via a file (as specified at http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/2452/30076)?

Comment: I would prefer that you take a string as input, but if you feel that you can provide an interesting and/or unique solution by using a file for input, please feel free to do so.

Comment: Are the spaces necessary?

Comment: Does it has to be ASCII? i.e., if a technology is not ASCII compatible, could the results reflect that?

Comment: Can we assume ASCII printable 32-127?  If so, can binary strings be 7 chars with left zero-padding?

Comment: Is it acceptable to output with a separator other than spaces (e.g. a newline)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## CJam, 8 bytes

```
l:i2fbS*
```

Easy-peasy:

```
l:i           "Read the input line and convert each character to its ASCII value";
   2fb        "Put 2 on stack and use that to convert each ASCII value to base 2";
      S*      "Join the binary numbers by space";
```

[Try it here](http://cjam.aditsu.net/)

Answer (score 14):

## Python 3, 41 bytes

```py
print(*[bin(ord(x))[2:]for x in input()])
```

Like [KSFT's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/44831/21487), but I thought I'd point out that, in addition to `raw_input -> input`, Python 3 also has an advantage here due to the splat for `print`.

Answer (score 9):

## Pyth, 10 bytes

```
jdmjkjCd2z
```

Python mapping and explanation:

```
j           # join(                               "Join by space"
 d          #      d,                             "this space"
 m          #      Pmap(lambda d:                 "Map characters of input string"
  j         #                    join(            "Join by empty string"
   k        #                        k,           "this empty string"
    j       #                        join(        "This is not a join, but a base conversion"
     C      #                             Pchr(   "Convert the character to ASCII"
      d     #                                  d  "this character"
            #                                 ),
     2      #                             2       "Convert to base 2"
            #                            )
            #                        ),
  z         #           z)))                      "mapping over the input string"
```

Input is the string that needs to be converted without the quotes.

[Try it here](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/)

Comment: Is asdfghjlkl also a valid pyth program? What does it do?

Comment: @flawr any harm in trying ? ;)

Comment: @flawr That compiles to the python `Psum(d).append(Pfilter(lambda T:gte(head(join(Plen(k),Plen())))))`, whee d=' ' and k=''. So no, it is not valid at all.

Comment: Thanks for the Pyth solution. I just started learning it today, but I think it will take some time getting used to. Any suggestions?

Comment: @ericmark26 look around your room or office, and smash everything that you can find into your keyboard and see if it interprets. Figure out what it does, and then repeat with the next object. When you run out, try different rotations.

Comment: @ericmark26 I think the best way to get used to Pyth is to take some simple Python programs, and translate them into Pyth.

Answer (score 5):

## [MITS Altair 8800](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Altair_8800), 0 bytes

Input string is at memory address `#0000H` ([allowed](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8510/84624)).  Output in binary via front panel I/O lights `D7-D0`.

Example, do `RESET`, then `EXAMINE` to see the first byte, followed by repeating `EXAMINE NEXT` to see the rest.

`"H" = 01 001 000:`

[image]

`"e" = 01 100 101:`

[image]

`"l" = 01 101 100:`

[image]

[Try it online!](https://s2js.com/altair/sim.html)

Non-competing, of course. :)

Answer (score 4):

## Python 3 - 43 bytes

---

```
print(*map("{:b}".format,input().encode()))
```

No quite the shortest, but an interesting approach IMO. It has the added advantage that if the number of significant bits varies, E.G. `Hi!`, padding with zeros is trivial (2 more bytes, as opposed to 9 for `.zfill(8)`):

```
print(*map("{:08b}".format,input().encode()))
```

Answer (score 3):

## Python - 52

```
print" ".join([bin(ord(i))[2:]for i in raw_input()])
```

<s>I'll work on translating this into Pyth.</s> Someone else did a Pyth answer already.

If you don't care about it being a full program or about I/O format and use Python 3, you can do it in 23 bytes like this:

```
[bin(ord(i))for i in x]
```

`x` is the input.

I know this doesn't count because the interpreter wasn't released before the challenge was posted, but here it is in KSFTgolf:

```
oan
```

Answer (score 3):

## Ruby, <s>34</s> <s>28</s> 24 bytes

```
$<.bytes{|c|$><<"%b "%c}
```

Takes input via STDIN. 6 bytes saved thanks for AShelly and another 4 thanks to britishtea.

Comment: trim by 6 with `$<.each_byte{|c|$><<"%b "%c}`

Comment: You can shave off some more characters by using `String#bytes` instead of `String#each_byte`. The block form is deprecated, but it still works :)

Comment: @britishtea Oh, nice. thank you!

Answer (score 3):

## PowerShell, <s>63</s> <s>59</s> 46 bytes

-13 bytes thanks to @mazzy

```
"$($args|% t*y|%{[Convert]::ToString(+$_,2)})"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/X0lFQyWxKL24RlWhRKuyRrU62jk/ryy1qCTWyiokP7ikKDMvXUNbJV7HSLNWU@k/UIMHUF@@jkJ4flFOiqISAA)

Comment: ? [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/X0lFQyWxKL24RlWhRKuyRrU62jk/ryy1qCTWyiokP7ikKDMvXUNbJV7HSLNWU@k/UIMHUF@@jkJ4flFOiqISAA "PowerShell – Try It Online")

Answer (score 3):

## [Forth (gforth)](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/Docs-html/), 45 bytes

```forth
: f 0 do dup i + c@ 2 base ! . decimal loop ;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcVBDkAwEEDRq/zaChFLNpZuYI1paTIyjXL@ird5we7nbI7wV8pAoEMMeRORmn2iZ1uzx9Eifo/XqqhZYiy5YvaqxmK3iqsI5QM)

#### Code Explanation

```forth
: f           \ start a new word definition
  0 do        \ start a loop from 0 to string length - 1
    dup i +   \ duplicate the address and add the loop index to get addr of current character
    c@        \ get the character at that address
    2 base !  \ set the base to binary
    .         \ print the ascii value (in binary)
    decimal   \ set the base back to decimal
  loop        \ end the loop
;             \ end the word definition
```

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript ES6, 63 <strike>65</strike> bytes

```js
alert([for(c of prompt())c.charCodeAt().toString(2)].join(' '))
```

This is rather long, thanks to JavaScript's long function names. The Stack Snippet below is the rough ES5 equivalent, so it can be run in any browser. Thanks to edc65 for the golfing improvements.

```js
alert(prompt().split('').map(function(e){return e.charCodeAt().toString(2)}).join(' '))
```

Comment: `[for of]` is slightly shorter than `[...].map` to enumerate charactes in strings: `alert([for(c of prompt())c.charCodeAt().toString(2)].join(' '))`

Comment: You can golf off two bytes by replacing `.join(' ')` with ``.join` ` ``. You can golf off a lot of bytes by using a function instead of `prompt`/`alert`

Answer (score 2):

## Matlab

This is an anonymous function

```
f=@(x) dec2bin(char(x))
```

usage is `f('Hello World')`.

Alternatively, if `x` is defined as the string `Hello World!` in the workspace, then just `dec2bin(char(x))` will work.

Comment: I'm not sure about how to score this because I'm not sure how I can get the input. Any comments?

Comment: Why `char`? I think you mean `dec2bin(x)-'0'`

Comment: Because I'm not that clever!

Comment: My point is: `char(x)`, when `x` is already a string, does nothing. So you can remove it to save some space. On the other hand, the result of `dec2bin` is a string, and I think the output should be numbers

Comment: I understand, and you are right, of course. Matlab makes it easy to forget about data types sometimes.

Answer (score 2):

## J - 9

```
1":#:3&u:
```

No idea how to make this in a row without doubling the length of the code, I need J gurus to tell me :)

```
1":#:3&u:'Hello world!'
1001000
1100101
1101100
1101100
1101111
0100000
1110111
1101111
1110010
1101100
1100100
0100001
```

Comment: You can add `".` to the beginning. It evaluates your result so it will be in one line and separated by spaces. Even shorter is to create base10 numbers with the base2 digits: `10#.#:3&u:`.

Answer (score 2):

## Java  - 148 Bytes

```
public class sToB{public static void main(String[] a){for(int i=0;i<a[0].length();i++){System.out.print(Integer.toString(a[0].charAt(i) ,2)+" ");}}}
```

Edited to include full file

Comment: I think OP wants a full program, not just a snippet. Plus, it can be golfed a lot more, methinks.

Comment: that is the full program, if you put that in a main class, it will run.
as for better golfing, probably but i could not spot how.

Comment: The full program includes the main class, too.

Comment: could be shorter using `for(char c:a[0].toCharArray()){` or even `for(byte b:a[0].getBytes()){` since the input is ascii, assuming a non-utf-16 machine locale

Comment: nice, I would never have thought of that. thank you.

Comment: You can get rid of the `public` and shorten the program name to a single char to win more bytes. Plus, `(String[]a)`is perfectly accepted by the compiler, earning you another byte.

Comment: I know it's been more than 2.5 year, but you can save 20 bytes like this: `interface B{static void main(String[]a){for(Integer i=0;i<a[0].length();)System.out.print(i.toString(a[0].charAt(i++),2)+" ");}}`

Answer (score 2):

## Scala - <strike>59</strike> - 55 Bytes

```
readLine().map(x=>print(x.toByte.toInt.toBinaryString))
```

Normally, one should use foreach and not map.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3.6](https://docs.python.org/3.6/), 39 bytes

```python
print(*[f'{ord(c):b}'for c in input()])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzv6AoM69EQys6Tb06vyhFI1nTKqlWPS2/SCFZITMPiApKSzQ0YzX///dIzcnJVwjPL8pJUQQA)

Answer (score 2):

## x86-16 machine code, IBM PC DOS, <del>33</del> <del>31</del> 28 bytes

**Binary:**

```
00000000: d1ee ad8a c849 b308 ac92 b000 d0e2 1430  .....I.........0
00000010: cd29 4b75 f5b0 20cd 29e2 ebc3            .)Ku.. .)...
```

**Listing:**

```
D1 EE       SHR  SI, 1          ; point SI to DOS PSP (80H) 
AD          LODSW               ; load input string length into AL, SI to 82H  
8A C8       MOV  CL, AL         ; set up loop counter 
49          DEC  CX             ; remove leading space/slash from char count 
        LOOP_CHAR: 
B3 08       MOV  BL, 8          ; loop 8 bits 
AC          LODSB               ; load next char 
92          XCHG AX, DX         ; use DX for bit shift 
        LOOP_BIT: 
B0 00       MOV  AL, 0          ; clear AL 
D0 E2       SHL  DL, 1          ; high-order bit into CF 
14 30       ADC  AL, '0'        ; AL = '0' + CF              
CD 29       INT  29H            ; write AL to screen 
4B          DEC  BX             ; decrement bit counter 
75 F5       JNZ  LOOP_BIT       ; loop next bit              
B0 20       MOV  AL, ' '        ; display a space 
CD 29       INT  29H            ; write AL to screen 
E2 EB       LOOP LOOP_CHAR      ; loop next char 
C3          RET                 ; return to DOS
```

A standalone PC DOS executable COM file. Input is via command line, output to screen.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby, 24 bytes

I was hoping to beat [Martin Ender](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/44836/11261), but I only managed to tie him.

Takes input on STDIN; +1 bytes for `-p` flag.

```ruby
gsub(/./){"%b "%$&.ord}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/P724NElDX09fs1pJNUlBSVVFTS@/KKX2/3@P1JycfIXw/KKcFMV/@QUlmfl5xf91CwA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 39 bytes

```python
print(*[f'{ord(i):b}'for i in input()])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v6AoM69EQys6Tb06vyhFI1PTKqlWPS2/SCFTITMPiApKSzQ0YzX///dIzcnJVwjPL8pJUQQA)

Slight improvement over the [current leading Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/44846/87681)

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal) `S`, 3 bytes

```
bƛṅ
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=S&code=b%C6%9B%E1%B9%85&inputs=Hello%2C%20World!&header=&footer=)

Explanation:

```
b    # Convert each letter to a list of bits
 ƛ   # In each list of bits:
  ṅ  #   Join elements
     # 'S' flag - join top of stack with spaces and output
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/), <strike>47</strike> 45 bytes

```rust
|s:&str|for i in s.bytes(){print!("{:b} ",i)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY2xCoMwGIRn8xR/MpQI0gdQOnWwU7dSSumg9Q8E0vySRKFonj1NHVzuu@MOzk0@JGXh02kry4UZDKBOafX1wQe3KnKgQVvwx/4b0OfJ6LQNXIql7iOISpcxNWzfzfjmT3FBYwju5MzARSXONCC0ZFT2V5zRZbZkbfennjHjQVPW2yheCyv2iwj1dtGwQskNW2UslzlEFtMP)

A closure iterating over the string, converting each character to its ascii number, then printing out it's binary equivalent with `:b`

Turns out you don't need `{}` always to define a closure

Answer (score 1):

## C++ - 119 bytes

Freeing memory? What's that?

```
#include<cstdio>
#include<cstdlib>
int main(int c,char**v){for(*v=new char[9];c=*(v[1]++);printf("%s ",itoa(c,*v,2)));}
```

(MSVC compiles the code with warning)

Comment: C version, shorter `main(int c,char**v){char x[9];for(;c=*(v[1]++);printf("%s ",itoa(c,x,2)));}`

Answer (score 1):

## Haskell, 65

```
m s=tail$do c<-s;' ':do j<-[6,5..0];show$mod(fromEnum c`div`2^j)2
```

heavy use of the list monad. it couldn't be converted to list comprehentions because the last statements weren't a `return`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 52 bytes

```
proc B s {binary s $s B* b;regsub -all .{8} $b {& }}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0nO@f@/oCg/WcFJoVihOikzL7GoEshSKVZw0lJIsi5KTS8uTVLQTczJUdCrtqhVUElSqFZTqK39X1BaUqwQ7aSg5JGak5OvUJ5flJOiqBT7/z@UDwA)

Comment: Unfortunately the program version has more bytes due to the join: [`binary scan [join $argv] B* b;puts [regsub -all .{8} $b {& }]`](https://tio.run/##K0nO@f8/KTMvsahSoTg5MU8hOis/M09BJbEovSxWwUlLIcm6oLSkWCG6KDW9uDRJQTcxJ0dBr9qiVkElSaFaTaE29v///x6pOTn5CuX5RTkpigA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 3 bytes

```
OBK
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/fyfv////qHkBevo5CeH5RToqiOgA)

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 12 bytes

```apl
10⊥2⊥⍣¯1⎕UCS
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT////1FH26O2CYYGj7qWGgHxo97Fh9YbPuqbGuocDJZUUPdIzcnJ11EIzy/KSVFUBwA)

Thanks to [Adám](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/43319/ad%C3%A1m) for help with this solution.

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript ES6, 71 bytes

```javascript
alert(prompt().split('').map(c=>c.charCodeAt(0).toString(2))).join(' ')
```

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! You need `.split('')` to split at the empty string; `.split()` turns `"abc"` into `["abc"]`.

Answer (score 1):

## Commodore VIC-20/C64/128 and TheC64Mini, 101 tokenized BASIC bytes

Here is the obfuscated listing using Commodore BASIC keyword abbreviations:

```
 0dEfnb(x)=sG(xaNb):inputa$:fOi=1tolen(a$):b=64:c$=mI(a$,i,1):fOj=0to6
 1?rI(str$(fnb(aS(c$))),1);:b=b/2:nEj:?" ";:nE
```

Here for explanation purposes is the non-obfuscated symbolic listing:

```
 0 def fn b(x)=sgn(x and b)
 1 input a$
 2 for i=1 to len(a$)
 3 let b=64
 4 let c$=mid$(a$,i,1)
 5 for j=0 to 6
 6 print right$(str$(fn b(asc(c$))),1);
 7 let b=b/2
 8 next j
 9 print " ";
10 next i
```

The function `fn b` declared on line zero accepts a numeric parameter of `x` which is `AND`ed with the value of `b`; [SGN](https://www.c64-wiki.com/wiki/SGN) is then used to convert `x and b` to `1` or `0`.

Line one accept a string input to the variable `a$`, and the loop starts (denoted with `i`) to the length of that input. `b` represents each bit from the 6th to 0th bit. `c$` takes each character of the string at position `i`.

line 5 starts the loop to test each bit position; `right$` is used in line 6 to remove a auto-formatting issue when Commodore BASIC displays a number, converting the output of `fn b` to a string; `asc(c$)` converts the current character to its ascii code as a decimal value.

Line 7 represents the next bit value. The loop `j` is ended before printing a space, then the last loop `i` is ended.

[image: C64 converting PETSCII to Binary]

Answer (score 1):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 34 bytes

```
i\~48*o
?\:0(?;:2%:}-2,:0=
?\{nl1=
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/PzOmzsRCK5/LPsbKQMPe2spI1apW10jHysAWKFSdl2No@/@/R2pOTr5CeH5RTooiAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 4 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
Çbðý
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//cHvS4Q2H9/7/75Gak5OvEJ5flJOiCAA)

**Explanation:**

```python
Ç     # Convert the (implicit) input-string to a list of unicode values
 b    # Convert each integer to a binary string
  ðý  # Join by spaces (and output the result implicitly)
```

Could be just the first two bytes if a list output is allowed, or 3 bytes with `»` if a newline delimiter instead of space delimiter is allowed.

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 21 bytes

```perl
printf'%b ',ord for@F
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/7@gKDOvJE1dNUlBXSe/KEUhLb/Iwe3//0SFJIVkhRSFVIW0f/kFJZn5ecX/dd0A)

Answer (score 1):

## [Gaia](https://github.com/splcurran/Gaia), 4 bytes

```
ċb¦ṡ
```

Pretty happy with this

## How it works

```
ċ   Get a list of all the code points in the input string
b¦  Convert every number in that list to binary
ṡ   Joins the element of the list with spaces
Implicit Output
```

[Try it Online!](https://tio.run/##S0/MTPz//0h30qFlD3cu/P/fIzUnJ18hPL8oJ0URAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/) `--extendedglob`, 30 bytes

```sh
<<<${1//(#m)?/$[[##2]#MATCH] }
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@F@cWpJfUKKQWlGSmpeSmpKek5/ElaahWf3fxsZGpdpQX19DOVfTXl8lOlpZ2ShW2dcxxNkjVqH2fy0XV5qCukdqTk6@Qnh@UU6Kovp/AA)

`//`Replace every `(#m)` matched `?` single character with its binary representation. `[#2]` leaves a `2#` prefix on, `[##2]` strips it.

---

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), <s>43</s> 36 bytes

```sh
for c (${(s::)1})printf $[[##2]#c]\
```

<s>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@J@moVn9Py2/SCFZQUOlWqPYykrTsFYzNTkjX0GlWkVDI1rZKFY5WVNT2d6@Vl0hJln9fy0XV5qCukdqTk6@Qnh@UU6Kovp/AA)
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@J@moVn9Py2/SCFZQUOlWqPYykrTsFazoCgzryRNQaVaRUMjWtkoVjlZU1PZ3r42RuF/LRdXmoK6R2pOTr5CeH5RToqi@n8A)</s>
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@J@moVn9Py2/SCFZQUOlWqPYykrTsFazoCgzryRNQUVDI1pZ2ShWOVlTM0bhfy0XV5qCukdqTk6@Qnh@UU6Kovp/AA)

```sh
for c (${(s::)1})                           # for character in string $1   (e.g. H)
                       $[       ]          # arithmetic evaluation
                       $[     #c]          # get character code           (e.g. 72)
                       $[[##2]#c]          # convert to base 2            (e.g. 1001000)
               printf  $[       ]\    # append space, print
```

---

If all binary strings need to be 8 characters long, **+5 bytes**:

```sh
for c (${(s::)1})printf %08d\  $[[##2]#c]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@J@moVn9Py2/SCFZQUOlWqPYykrTsFazoCgzryRNQdXAIiVGQUElOlpZ2ShWOTn2fy0XV5qCukdqTk6@Qnh@UU6Kovp/AA)

Comment: using printf for [43 bytes](https://tio.run/##qyrO@J@moVn9Py2/SCFZQUOlWqPYykrTsFazoCgzryRNQaVaRUMjWtkoVjlZU1PZ3r42RuF/LRdXmoK6R2pOTr5CeH5RToqi@n8A)

Answer (score 1):

## Shakti, <s>8</s> 3 bytes

In 2020.02.19:

```
10/2\`c?
```

Example:

```
 10/2\`c?"Hello World!"
1001000 1100101 1101100 1101100 1101111 100000 1010111 1101111 1110010 1101100 1100100 100001
```

Update: **3 bytes** in 2020.02.23, via Arthur: `2\'`

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), 52 bytes

```javascript
a=>[...a].map(p=>p.charCodeAt().toString(2)).join` `
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcGxCoMwEADQX1Gnu6E3OBUkgnRxd3AoBY8YNXLmQgz@fvreyQ/fNvmYX8@7bKaw6b9ExD@6OEI0fSR7cPro6oYMSFmnnHzYoUWkU31YqqV0VsOt4kh0hw2a0YloNWuStW4Qyx8)

Beats all existing JS answers.

Answer (score 1):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), <s>465</s> <s>455</s> <s>443</s> 356 bytes

```
>>,[<+<+>>-]<[[-]>+++++++>+[>[-]>>[-]<<<<<<[>>>>+>+<<<<<-]>>>>[<<<<+>>>>-]<<[>>+>>+<<<<-]>>>>[<<<<+>>>>-]<<[>>[-]++<[->-[>+>>]>[+[-<+>]>+>>]<<<<<]>>[-]>[<<<+>>>-]<<<<-]>>[-]++<[>->+<[>]>[<+>-]<<[<]>-]<<[-]>>>>[<<<+<+>>>>-]<<<<<<[>>>+<<<-]>>>[[-]>>[-]-[<+>-----]<---[<<+<<+>>>>-]<<.[-]>]<<[>+>+<<-]>>-[<<+>>-]<]++++[>++++++++<-]>.<<<<[-]>[-]>[-],[<+<+>>-]<]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVBLCgIxDL2KrmPmBCVrb@DikYVfEIsDA56/5qVTxo2BSZt5n6S5LOfn@/G5vlozO6BIETP1Aqib9DCBsWQqGbCI@J8FkcB4Fd5IAuGO/4HDS6RATUGqGwQaDM8qjXvHlMoq7Har1tSYyZBuG5I8t56yNR2DyxgK41GaBgwvkUDZpptIy6HzxdQkJVHngjA2JUSnbMTB@/ezVW/teK913p3mpd72Xw)

Answer (score 1):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), <s>12</s> 6 bytes

```
{2\'x}
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.bitbucket.io/k/#eJxLs6o2ilGvqOXiSlPySM3JyVcIzy/KSVFUAgBk3gfB)

*-6 bytes thanks to @coltim*

Returns a 2D array.

Comment: I think this can be just [`2\'`](https://ngn.bitbucket.io/k/#eJxLszKKUefiSlPySM3JyVcIzy/KSVFUAgBE0gZR)

Answer (score 0):

### STATA 158

I used a different approach than most. Read in via the display _request() prompt (shortened to di _r(r)). Write the string to a file called b in text mode. Open b in binary mode and read each character as a byte and convert to binary. Technically the b file should be closed at the end, but it is a valid program and runs successfully without it.

```
di _r(r)
file open a using "b",w
file w a "$r"
file close a
file open a using "b",b r
file r a %1bu t
while r(eof)==0 {
loc q=t
inbase 2 `q'
file r a %1bu t
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Golang - 68

I'm new to Go and I'm not sure on the rules for counting characters in this language on here either.

Imports (11 bytes):

```
import"fmt"
```

Function (55 bytes):

```
func c(s string){for _,r:=range s{fmt.Printf("%b ",r)}}
```

You can run it [here](https://play.golang.org/).

Comment: You can golf this with `import."fmt"` and then just using `Printf`.

Answer (score 0):

## Erlang, 71 Bytes

```
f(S)->L=lists,L:droplast(L:flatten([integer_to_list(X,2)++" "||X<-S])).
```

If a trailing whitespace at the end is allowed then

## 55 Bytes

```
f(S)->lists:flatten([integer_to_list(X,2)++" "||X<-S]).
```

Answer (score 0):

Never will C# win these kinds of questions but here's a try, completely without encoding. :)

## C# - 84

```
Console.Write(String.Join(" ",Console.ReadLine().Select(x=>Convert.ToString(x,2))));
```

Comment: This could be made much shorter by using a lambda function, ie: `x=>String.Join(" ",x.Select(y=>Convert.ToString(y,2)));` However note that, due to using `.Select()`, both this shorter answer, and your original answer, need to include the 18 bytes for `using System.Linq;` unless you specify that it's using the Visual C# Interactive Compiler, which imports System.Linq by default

Comment: [Here's](https://tio.run/##JYrLCsIwEAB/Jea0gZiDV00ughTxVqEfELeysOxCEqX9@vjoaRhmct3nSv3yknyqrZA8vdmYzBz7EtP4t3BVErDG@iWMyJgbrDGdVd5YWrjrdsHqD865Y/@GqoxhKtTwRoIwgx2QWb2ZtPBjZ3/bBw "C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler) – Try It Online") the lambda function solution using Interactive Compiler, total of 55 bytes

Answer (score 0):

## Cobra - 64

As a Lambda:

```cobra
do(s='')=(for c as int in s get Convert.toString(c,2)).join(' ')
```

Answer (score 0):

## Postscript, 17 bytes (13 byte program + 4 character command line switch)

```
s { 2 7 string cvrs = } forall
```

Which is 31 bytes in tokenized form: (backticks denote literal characters, everything else is hexidecimal)

```
`s{2 7` 92A5 9230 `=}` 9249
```

Run using Ghostscript as:

```
gs -ss="Hello World!" string-to-binary.ps
```

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript 78

```
alert(eval('""'+prompt().replace(/./g,"+' '+'$&'.charCodeAt().toString(2)")))
```

Answer (score 0):

## Ruby 38 Bytes

```
p gets.bytes.map{|i|i.to_s 2}.join ' '
```

Comment: `.join ' '` can be shortened to `*' '`.

Answer (score 0):

## Julia, 23 bytes

```
f(n)=[bin(a)for a in n]
```

Answer (score 0):

## [q/kdb+](http://kx.com/download/), 18 bytes

**Solution:**

```
" "sv"01"0b vs'4h$
```

**Example:**

```
q)" "sv"01"0b vs'4h$"Hello World!"
"01001000 01100101 01101100 01101100 01101111 00100000 01010111 01101111 01110010 01101100 01100100 00100001"
```

**Explanation:**

Convert string to byte array, convert each byte to binary, index into the string `"01"` and then join strings together with whitespace `" "`:

```
" "sv"01"0b vs'4h$ / the solution
               4h$ / cast ($) to type byte (4h)
         0b vs'    / convert each (') byte to binary (0b vs)
     "01"          / (implicit) index into "01" (false;true)
" "sv              / join (sv) with " "
```

Answer (score 0):

## Shell utils, 102 bytes

I'm kind of ashamed of this.

```
xxd -b|sed -r "s/^.*: //;s/  .+$//;s/0*([01]+)/\1/g"|tr \n\r " "|sed -r "s/ +/ /g;s/ *1101 *1010 *$//"
```

Since I'm (possibly) running utilities from various archives across the Internet on Windows, I'll list the version information for each:

```
xxd V1.10 27oct98 by Juergen Weigert
GNU sed version 4.2.1
tr (GNU textutils) 2.0
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.15063]
```

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, 59 bytes

```
<?foreach(str_split($argv[1])as$a)echo decbin(ord($a)).' ';
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DclBCoAgEADArxgI6aGgc0HXftAhIkwtBXFlV3p@W3OdEgrzNF@A3tigqOJBJcWqpMH72YZdG5JGextAOG/PmBWg@1frvhXtyMyLTwnECphc80KpETJxlz8)

Answer (score 0):

## [Deorst](https://github.com/SatansSon/Deorst), 8 bytes

```
vombkE]_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0nNLyou@f@/LD83Kds1Nv7///9KHqk5OfkK4flFOSmKSgA)

### How it works

Example input: `ab`

```
vo       - Map ordinal;      STACK = [[97, 98]]
  mb     - Map binary;       STACK = [['1100001', '1100010']]
    k    - Turn off sort;    STACK = [['1100001', '1100010']]
     E]  - Flatten;          STACK = ['110001', '1100010']
       _ - Join with spaces; STACK = ['110001 1100010']
```

Answer (score 0):

## Java 8, 112 bytes

Takes input as a command line argument

```
interface M{static void main(String[]a){a[0].chars().forEach(i->System.out.print(Long.toBinaryString(i)+" "));}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcyxCoMwEADQX0mdEoqhe6FDodChTg4dxOFIop7VXLlcBRG/PS10f7wRFihH/8oZowTuwAVVbUlA0KmF0KsZMOpaGGPftGA2aE6tdQNw0sZ2xDdwg8byUq9JwmzpI/b9w6IfFHsrdMUIvP4DjeZYqMKY877nnO9hmkg9iSd/@AI)

Comment: I'm so tired right now that I forgot I already did this challenge and almost posted a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-S`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 4 bytes

```
¬®c¤
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LVM&code=rK5jpA&input=IkhlbGxvIFdvcmxkISI)

```
¬®c¤     :Implicit input input of string U
¬        :Split
 ®       :Map
  c      :  Character code
   ¤     :  To binary string
         :Implicitly join with spaces and output
```

Or, if we can take input as an array of characters ...

### [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-mS`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 2 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
c¤
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LW1T&code=Y6Q&input=WyJIIiwiZSIsImwiLCJsIiwibyIsIiAiLCJXIiwibyIsInIiLCJsIiwiZCIsIiEiXQ)

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 16 bytes

```perl6
*.ords>>.base(2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPtfSy@/KKXYzk4vKbE4VcNI8781V3FipUKahpJHak5OvkJ4flFOiqKS5n8A)

Converts the string to codepoints and then each to base 2.

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 10 bytes

```
SvyÇ2Bнð«?

S           //Split string
 v          //Loop on every character
  y         //Push current character to the stack
   Ç        //Get ASCII value of character
    2B      //Convert to base 2
      н     //Convert from 1-element array to string
       ð«   //Append space
         ?  //Print with no newline
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8/uKzycLuR04W9hzccWm3//79Hak5OvkJ4flFOiuJ/AA)

Answer (score 0):

## Python 3, 39 bytes

```
for i in input():print(bin(ord(i))[2:])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/Py2/SCFTITMPiApKSzQ0rQqKMvNKNJIy8zTyi1I0MjU1o42sYjX///dIzcnJVwjPL8pJAQA)

Comment: Welcome to the site! While I'm sure it's a non-issue, the post asks for spaces, not newlines, between the binary chunks. I've commented on the question asking if newlines are acceptable for you. In addition, I've edited in a link to [Try it online!](https://tio.run) so that others can verify that your solution works.

Answer (score 0):

## Elixir 47

```
for c<-:io.read(''),do: :io.fwrite('~.2B ',[c])
```

As function:

```
& for<<c<-&1>>,do: :io.fwrite('~.2B ',[c])
```

As function working on charlists (`'` delimited strings):

```
& for c<-&1,do: :io.fwrite('~.2B ',[c])
```

Answer (score 0):

## Erlang 41

```erlang
[io:fwrite('~.2B ',[C])||C<-io:read("")].
```

Comment: How is this answer called?  Is it a complete program?  Is it a function? Is it something else?

Comment: Fixed to be full program.

Answer (score 0):

## [Burlesque](https://github.com/FMNSSun/Burlesque), 10 bytes

```
XX{**b2}mw
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyotykktLixN/Z@TV/0/IqJaSyvJqDa3/H9tbvR/j9ScnHyF8vyinBRFAA)

```
XX  # Break into characters
{
 ** # Convert to ascii val
 b2 # Convert to binary
}mw # Map and spaces between elements
```

Answer (score 0):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 44 bytes

```php
while($c=decbin(ord($argn[$i++])))echo"$c ";
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jXwAkyzMyc1I1VJJtU1KTkzLzNPKLUjRUEovS86JVMrW1YzU1NVOTM/KVVJIVlKz///dIzcnJVwjPL8pJUfyXX1CSmZ9X/F/XDQA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip) `-s`, 6 bytes

```
TB*A*a
```

Converts to ASCII/Unicode, then to binary. the `-s` flag joins lists on space.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P8/xEnLUSvx////Hqk5OfkK4flFOSmK/3WLAQ)

Answer (score 0):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 7 bytes

```
wm(ṁsḋc
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/vzxX4@HOxuKHO7qT////r@SRmpOTr6MQnl@Uk6KoBAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>2</s> 1 byte

```
b
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8/6f//aHMjHQVDA0MQYQEjDIFcY6C4hTmUY2hoAldgAJQzjgUA) Beats all other answers. Takes input as a list of code points.

Answer (score 0):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/), 40 bytes

```rust
|s|for c in s.bytes(){print!("{:b} ",c)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyotLvmflqeQm5iZp6FZnZNaopBmlZanoVZcUqSpYPu/prgmLb9IIVkhM0@hWC@psiS1GKisoCgzr0RRQ6naKqlWQUknWbP2vzVXmoaSR2pOTr6OQnh@UU6KopKmNRdMYUweiAdU8Wj2ZhCr9j8A)

An anonymous function that takes in an `&str`, iterates over bytes, and prints them as a binary string.

Answer (score 0):

## MUMPS, <s>77</s> 76 bytes

```
r s,! f i=1:1:$l(s) s r=$a($e(s,i)) s b=" " f  s b=(r#2)_b,r=r\2 i r=0 w b q
```

**Example**

```
REPL > r s w ! f i=1:1:$l(s) s r=$a($e(s,i)) s b=" " f  s b=(r#2)_b,r=r\2 i r=0 w b q
Hello World!
1001000 1100101 1101100 1101100 1101111 100000 1010111 1101111 1110010 1101100 1100100 100001
```

**Explanation**

- M is great at keeping things to one line.
- We assign user input to variable `s` and write a newline (`!`).
- For each character in our string, get the ASCII value with `$ascii()` and `$extract()` (intrinsic functions can be abbreviated).
- `b` is meant to hold the binary value of our character, but we will quickly set it to be a space since we need that to separate the binary representation of each character.
- Now we enter an unconditional loop (two spaces after declaring the for loop). We prefix `b` with out ascii value (`r`) modulo 2. You can do string operations on numbers in M.
- We then reduce our ascii value by half, disregarding the remainder (`\` is floor division)
- We do this until our ascii value hits 0, at which point we write our binary value

Answer (score 0):

## [Go](https://golang.org/), 116 bytes

```go
package main
import(."fmt";"os";."io/ioutil")
func main(){b,_:=ReadAll(os.Stdin);for c:=range b{Printf("%b ",b[c])}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Hcy7CsIwFADQvV8RLwgJlLg3dHBzFB0cRCTPcjHJLWk6lX57FPfDmai1WduPnjxLGnOHaaZSuYSQKiigBZQEpBPSWjGC6MKa7Z9ysZn@PYw3r905Rk6LvFeHWahAhdlhLDr/VrNdC@YaOBwNg9487Uvse2sXHyOxB5XoDu0L)

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2) `ṠB`, 1 [byte](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
ḃ
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faEW00sOdC5yUYhcsLS1J07VY_HBH85LipORiKH_BWo_UnJx8HYXw_KKcFEWIIAA)

##### Or, 4 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md) flagless:

```
Cḃðj
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faMGCpaUlaboWy50f7mg-vCFrSXFScjFUbMFaj9ScnHwdhfD8opwURYggAA)