# Convert a string of ASCII characters to base-3 equivalents

Tags: code-golf, string, base-conversion

Task similar to [this one](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/44830/string-to-binary). Take a string of ASCII characters and convert it to base-3 equivalents separated by a space.

For example:

```
Hello, world!
```

Should be converted to

```
02200 10202 11000 11000 11010 01122 01012 11102 11010 11020 11000 10201 01020
```

The output should only contain numbers with the same number of digits. Which separator to use is up to you.

This is a code-golf challenge so the shortest solution wins.

Comment: How should we pad the results?

Comment: What happens if the character codepoint is more than 999?

Comment: @Fmbalbuena *ASCII*

Comment: @emanresuA Oh sorry, Extended?

Comment: @emanresuA I think it doesn't matter (There are no limits)

Comment: So for `ABC` can the input be `2102 2110 2111` (no zero padding)? Please clarify in the challenge, maybe with a couple more examples. Also, how strict is the output format? Do we really need to use a space as separator? Can there be another separator between the digits?

Comment: Are the leading zeros in the output necessary? Why the strict output requirement (space separated rather than site default which would allow a list of lists etc...)?

Comment: All numbers must have the same number of digits (4, 5 or 6 it doesn't matter). The output must be a string with a space as a separator.

Comment: @sinvec But why space as a separator? The site allows that, See [This](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2447/106959) (I can't find one, But the site still allows)

Comment: @Fmbalbuena Ok, answers can be accepted with any separator (It is really doesn't matter for my task :))

Comment: @sinvec Can you edit the question to clarify the challenge?

Comment: @Fmbalbuena Those are site _defaults_. If the challenge author decides on spaces only, that's perfectly fine.

Comment: @RadvylfPrograms Oh, nevermind

Comment: Is a trailing separator acceptable?

Comment: @JonathanAllan Yes.

Comment: May we use excess leading zeros? Eg. pad every character to 10 digits? Also, please add clarifications from the comments to the challenge body (like loosening separator requirement).

Comment: Just to be clear, is a list of strings acceptable as output? There is at least one answer that gives such output.

Comment: @chunes If it's more convenient for you, then use lists (As I already wrote, it doesn't matter to the task)

Answer (score 9):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 3 bytes

```
3YA
```

Uses newline as separator. [**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/3zjS8f9/dY/UnJx8HYXy/KKcFEV1AA)

#### Explanation (by [@Sundar R](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/8774/sundar-r))

`YA` is a single function, corresponding to Matlab's [`dec2base`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dec2base.html) (convert from decimal to some base). By default it takes two arguments: an array with the numbers to convert and the base to convert to. Since only the second argument (`3`) is specified here, the input is implicitly used as the first argument.

The cool part is that this is automatically applied to the whole input (which is a char array), the results collected into a char matrix, and when things don't line up, `0`'s are automatically prepended to make them have the same width.

Comment: ok this is this is insanely short, what does the `Y` and `A` do though?

Comment: @DialFrost `YA` is a single command `dec2base` (convert decimal to some base) that takes two arguments - the number to convert and the base to convert to. Since we've specified only the second argument (3) here, the input is automatically prepended as the first argument.

Comment: The cool part is that its automatically applied to the whole input (which is seen as a char array), the results collected into a matrix, and when things don't line up, 0's are automatically prepended to make them have the same width.

Comment: @SundarR Thanks! Your comments describe what the code does so well that I incorporated them into the answer (with proper credit); I hope you don't mind

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/),  <s>70 66</s>  62? 66 bytes

```python
for c in input():print(*[ord(c)//d%3for d in b'Q    '],sep='')
```

(Code contains unprintable bytes inside the `b'...'`)

A full program accepting input from STDIN that prints the result using a newline separator (with a trailing newline).

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/Py2/SCFZITMPiApKSzQ0rQqKMvNKNLSi84tSNJI19fVTVI1BalJAapLUA6U5mRnVY3WKUwts1dU1///3SM3JyddRKM8vyklRBAA)**

---

...but 66 if we need to handle multi-line strings (since `input()` only reads one line:

```python
lambda s:[print(*[ord(c)//d%3for d in b'Q   '],sep='')for c in s]
```

An unnamed function that prints the answer.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUaHYKrqgKDOvREMrOr8oRSNZU18/RdU4Lb9IIUUhM08hST1QmpOZUT1Wpzi1wFZdXRMkkwySKY79X5JaXKJgq6Curh7D5ZGak5Ovw1WeX5SToggU4UrTAElr/odIKEAkAA)

Comment: sigh i took to long to come up with this answer

Comment: @DialFrost I thought I might not get there since I spent a while golfing the other Python answer.

Comment: ok now ur hacking @JonathanAllan 62 bytes!!!! how (Nice use of unprintable chars)

Comment: link for 2nd code? and im pretty sure the 2nd on is 64 bytes???

Comment: @DialFrost - added. There are unprintable characters in there.

Comment: oh thats why sry my bad (if im right there might be a way to get rid of the sep="")

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 9 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

<sup>All-ASCII jelly code to boot...</sup>

```
Ob3Uz0ZUK
```

A full program accepting a string that prints the result.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/98/yTi0yiAq1Pv///9KHkCxfB2F8vyinBRFJQA)**

#### How?

```
Ob3Uz0ZUK - Main Link: list of characters
O         - ordinals
 b3       - to base three
   U      - upend (reverse each)
    z0    - transpose with filler of zero
      Z   - transpose
       U  - upend (reverse each)
        K - join with spaces
          - implicit, smashing print
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 71 bytes

```python
import numpy
for i in input():print(numpy.base_repr(ord(i),3).zfill(5))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Hck7CoAwDADQ3VPELQEp2OLiZcQvBmwbYjvUy1cR3vakpDMGVyt7iZogZC@lOaICA4eP5IQ0inJI@KdZ5nufdBfFqBsydY7Mc/B14UBUa2/dvKxtC2Bf)

-30 thanks to Jonathan Allan, I'm lazy to golf another code

Prints numbers separated by newlines

If you really need space as a separator then here is the code:

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 176 bytes

```python
import numpy
m=input()
y=m[:-1]
u=lambda x:"0"*(5-len(x))+x
for i in y:print(u(str(numpy.base_repr(ord(i),base=3))),end = " ")
print(u(str(numpy.base_repr(ord(m[-1]),base=3))))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hY5LCsIwFAD3OcVrVu9pK7bFTSAnKSKpjRhoPqQJNKePn5U7twMzTCjp6d1Yq7HBxwQu21CYlcaFnJBYkXYSXX9lWa7KzouCXfAzP@ClW7XDnei4s4ePYMA4KCJE4xJm3FLEb@s0q03fog4RfVzQUPsBciSiVrsFJHDgxP55dnpP/LhUaz@Mar43DcDwAg)

Comment: `print(numpy.base_repr(ord(i),3).zfill(5))` saves 30.

Comment: This only saves 1, Can you show me the full code?

Comment: [TIO](https://tio.run/##Hck7CoAwDADQ3VPELQEp2OLiZcQvBmwbYjvUy1cR3vakpDMGVyt7iZogZC@lOaICA4eP5IQ0inJI@KdZ5nufdBfFqBsydY7Mc/B14UBUa2/dvKxtC2Bf) (also, use @ to notify :))

Comment: (Actually it shouldn't need @ since I am the only one who commented - just got notified after 10 mins :/)

Comment: @JonathanAllan Thanks

Comment: [152 bytes for 2nd one](https://tio.run/##ZctLCoMwEADQfU4xZjXTKlSlm4AnkVKSGmnAfBgT0NOnhS67fy@d@R3DWOvK0UMoPp3gfIqcwejdPtkmBr2DEX5yIZWMJMq0aW8WDYeSN3nBe7fZgAfR9RBrZHDgAvhZdf1DJXYhY8E9MxqMvKCjdiSi1oZlkiBJ/BM/f@uPUa39MGrzahqA4QM)

Comment: [1st one also 71 bytes](https://tio.run/##DcI7CoAwDADQ3VPELRERtLh4GfHTYsA2IdZBL199PH3yIcmVEkwipDvqAxxVLDdVEAMGTn@9M9Kkxinjulx@Nq@GYjsytY66N/B54khUSj@4Zd3qGmD4AA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 14 bytes

```
⪫ＥＳ⭆◧⍘℅ι³¦⁵Σλ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMMrPzNPwzexQMMzr6C0JLgEKJiuoamjAGGBJAISU3xS00o0nBKLU6Hy/kUpmXmJORqZQIXGQGwK0lCaq5GjqQlkKSkoaWpa///vkZqTk6@jUJ5flJOiyPVftywHAA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
  Ｓ             Input string
 Ｅ              Map over characters
       ι        Current character
      ℅         ASCII code
     ⍘  ³       Convert to base 3
    ◧     ⁵     Left pad to length 5
   ⭆            Map over characters and join
            λ   Inner character
           Σ    Numeric value if any
⪫               Join with spaces
                Implicitly print
```

12 bytes to print as a list:

```
ＵＢ0←Ｅ⮌Ｓ⮌⍘℅ι³
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NcmxCsIwEIDhvU8RO10gguBmt04KFcU@wZGcNXgk5ZrWxz8z6D9@v3@h@IysOlLp0b8nyWsK0B5a2zV3ianAaaBnceaKMzxoI1kILmley1jqnsBaZ/7e40I/vkmICRli3Udb61TPxJyd@WThsGt0v/EX) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
ＵＢ0
```

Set output to zero fill.

```
←Ｅ⮌Ｓ⮌
```

Output the strings upside-down and reversed (which right-justifies them) given by...

```
⍘℅ι³
```

... converting the ASCII codes to base 3.

Answer (score 3):

## [Javascript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), <s>62</s> 59 bytes

```js
f=

x=>[...x].map(t=>(t.charCodeAt()+243).toString(3).slice(1))

console.log((f+'').length);
console.log(f("Hello World!")+'');
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcmxCoMwEADQX6lOF9oetLpGEJfuHcUhxGhTzpwkR/Xv02wP3tf8TLLR73IPPLu86HzqbkTEc8LN7CC6A0H7MXEo3wuo67NtFAq/JfqwQnEibx08lMqWQ2JySLzCAvXLEfHtcnCkuarL/wE)

-3 thanks to @tsh

Comment: I believe you don't need the `+''`.

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>63</s> 59 bytes

```r
function(s)write(rep(utf8ToInt(s),e=5)%/%3^(4:0)%%3,1,,,"")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qflFicamz7P600L7kkMz9Po1izvCizJFWjKLVAo7QkzSIk3zOvBCiqk2prqqmqr2ocp2FiZaCpqmqsY6ijo6OkpAkxQkPJIzUnJ19HoTy/KCdFESgMAA)

<s>Nothing clever, but a straightforward implementation in R is shorter than anything else that I can think of so far...</s>
To avoid the penalty of defining a base-conversion `function` to use on each character, we repeat each character value 5 times, and then use vectorized integer division (`%/%`) and modulo (`%%`) to calculate all the base-3 digits.  Then, by lucky co-incidence, the `write` function splits its output data into a column width of 5 by default.

Answer (score 3):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 9 bytes

```
C3τvṅ5∆Z⁋
```

Uses newline as the separator.

```
C3τvṅ5∆Z⁋
C            Convert to ASCII codepoint
 3τ          Convert each character to base 3
   vṅ        Join by nothing, because to-base returns a list of digits
     5∆Z     Pad with 5 zeros (because that's the max length of an ASCII char)
        ⁋    Join by newlines
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCJDM8+EduG5hTXiiIZa4oGLIiwiIiwiSGVsbG8sIHdvcmxkISJd)

<strike>It will probably get 9 bytes soon, because of a bug (to-base doesn't support vectorization)</strike>
Lyxal epic speed bug fix done

Actually, [8 bytes with flag](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJqIiwiIiwiQzPPhHbhuYU14oiGWiIsIiIsIkhlbGxvLCB3b3JsZCEiXQ==), but `j` is very buggy

Answer (score 3):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), <s>38</s> 34 bytes

```
[ [ 3 >base "%05s "printf ] each ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcWxCsIwEAbgvU/xG3ATKYhLBVd16VI6lQ7XeLHFM6l3ER8/@i1fIJ@Tlr67tZcGT9bIgpD0RTkv8YH/834lNVYYvz8cPRtOVeWuLJJ2@CaV@8aVAQMOOE9kDLetjwa36hJzwAgmP2MsnkTKDw)

- `[ ... ] each` For each code point in the input string,
- `3 >base` convert it to base 3
- `"%05s "printf` and print it with leading zeros to a length of five, followed by a space.

Answer (score 2):

## [GeoGebra](https://geogebra.org/calculator), <s>74</s> 50 bytes

```
Zip(Take(ToBase(a,3),2,6),a,TextToUnicode("")+243)
```

Insert string input between the `""`. (I guess this is [allowed](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/60478046#60478046)) Output is a list of strings padded to 5 digits. (This is also [allowed](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/243100/convert-a-string-of-ascii-characters-to-base-3-equivalents/243151#comment547493_243100) by OP)

Uses the " add \$3^5\$ " idea from [@DLosc](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/16766/dlosc)'s [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/243152/96039).

[Try It On GeoGebra!](https://www.geogebra.org/calculator/zfzbsmn4)

Answer (score 2):

## [BQN](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/), 20 bytes

```
{'0'+3|⌊÷3⋆⌽↕5}¨-⟜@
```

Anonymous function that takes a string and returns a list of strings. [Run it online!](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/try.html#code=RiDihpAgeycwJyszfOKMivCdlanDtzPii4bijL3ihpU1fcKoLeKfnEAKCkYgIkhlbGxvLCBXb3JsZCEi)

If a list of lists of digits is an acceptable output format, then it's 16 bytes:

```
{3|⌊÷3⋆⌽↕5}¨-⟜@
```

#### Explanation

```
{'0'+3|⌊÷3⋆⌽↕5}¨-⟜@
                  -⟜@  Subtract '\0' from each character, converting to list of charcodes
{               }¨      Map this function to each charcode:
              ↕5          Range(5) 
            ⌽            Reverse
          3⋆              3 to the power of each
        ÷                Divide the argument by each
       ⌊                  Floor
     3|                   Mod 3
 '0'+                     Convert digits to characters by adding '0'
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Burlesque](https://github.com/FMNSSun/Burlesque), 14 bytes

```
)**m{3B!5'0P[}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyotykktLixN/f9fU0srt9rYSdFU3SAguvb/f4/UnJx8HYXy/KKcFEUA)

```
)**     # Map ord
m{      # Map
 3B!    # To base 3
 5'0P[  # Pad to length 5 using "0"s
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## APL+WIN, 22 bytes

Prompts for ASCII string. Index origin = 0

```
(⍕¨(⊂5⍴3)⊤¨⎕av⍳⎕)~¨' '
```

Most of the bytes are taken by formatting the output.

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 11 bytes

```
m(↑_5ṁsΘB3c
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/P1fjUdvEeNOHOxuLz81wMk7@//@/R2pOTr6OQnl@UU6KIgA)

5 bytes (`m(B3c`) to calculate the base-3 representation of each ASCII character, but then 6 more bytes to format the output: prepend a zero (`Θ`), get string representation of digits (`s`), flatten together (`ṁ`), and take the last 5 elements (`↑_5`).

If it's acceptable for the base-3 digits to be space-separated (and the groups to be newline-separated), then we could do it in [10 bytes](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/P1ej/FHbxHjTczOcjJP////vkZqTk6@jUJ5flJOiCAA): `m(w↑_5ΘB3c`.
If we insist on space-separating the non-separated base-3 digits (exactly as in the example), it'll cost [12 bytes](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/vzxX41HbxHjThzsbi8/NcDJO/v//v0dqTk6@jkJ5flFOiiIA): `wm(↑_5ṁsΘB3c`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>72 64</s> 62 bytes

```hs
unwords.map(\c->show.(`mod`3).div(fromEnum c)=<<[81,27,9,3,1])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DczRCsIgFADQX7mNHhScsPZQwewt6B9aMNFsknpFW/v7bjsfcGZd388QyKmRlrRisVVGndlo2kudcZVsiminnkvrv8wVjNe0RDBcDcP91InDUZxFL7oHp6h9AgW5@PSBPbjmtsUoYEuD3TX0My7oV6XW5PwH)

- Saved 8+2 Bytes thanks to @ovs suggestions.

Couldn't find any golfy way for the list of powers of 3: tried (3^)<$>[4,3..0] with no gains.

Comment: `concatMap show$` can be shortened to `show=<<`.

Comment: Now you can combine `=<<` and `<$>` to a single `=<<`.

Comment: @ovs thanks for walking me through the golfing process, so much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 72 bytes

```c
i;f(char*s){for(;*s;++s,putchar(32))for(i=243;i/=3;)putchar(48+*s/i%3);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XZFhb4IwEIa/@ytuJCYtYGyLS7Z17stisv8g@@Bqq81YIbRGNuNfHysIDCWhOd577r3rIWY7Iepac4XEflOGFp9UXiIeWh5FNi4OrpFRwjBudL1ki4Tr@TLhuM8tHqLQzvU0wfxca@Pga6MNwnCagH9aV3DSOrt@hyWcgjeZZXkMx7zMtnfBmY8wWRVSOLntSMIYIUAJIwwoJU3cn5QAoZQxfxLaZOmFoW2WDaQPacMwMnTKjXVdP7GX4lOWXbu0WrG0enz1730Qw/g76av9EgA1l9RmKytfRngXPoPVPzJXqL8EnndCOCgcoqilcWt22dBoS97vsqkWeudXefg4KLW2rsykQQ5DBHREeF0U36hhYnD4P1GUflyFgjSY2jSA2UtqgmtCtVWY30wj/TTDD7kdaHA1qw55So1v0HjLzuo8Ode/QmWbna1nxz8)

Comment: Suggest `s+=printf(" ")` instead of `s++,putchar(32)`

Answer (score 0):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 15 bytes

```lisp
S3E5+A_TB3MaJ:s
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724ILNgWbSSboFS7IKlpSVpuhbrg41dTbUd40OcjH0TvayKIaJQyY3RSh6pOTn5Ogrl-UU5KYpwXQA)

Or, using the `-s` flag to do the output formatting, **12 bytes**:

```lisp
S3E5+A_TB3Ma
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724ILNgWbSSbrFS7IKlpSVpuhZrgo1dTbUd40OcjH0TIUJQmY3RSh6pOTn5Ogrl-UU5KYpwLQA)

#### Explanation

Pip doesn't have any padding builtins as of this writing, so we do the following instead: Add \$3^5\$ to each codepoint; convert to base 3, resulting in a 6-digit number that always has a leading 1; and slice off the first digit.

```lisp
S3E5+A_TB3MaJ:s
           a     ; First command-line argument
          M      ; Map this function to each of its characters:
     A_          ;   ASCII code of the character
 3E5+            ;   Add 3 to the 5th power
       TB3       ;   Convert to base 3
S                ;   Suffix containing all but the first character
            J:   ; Join the resulting list on
              s  ; Space
```

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E (legacy)](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/tree/fb4a2ce2bce6660e1a680a74dd61b72c945e6c3b), 9 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
Ç3Bí0ζøí»
```

Output is newline delimited.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##ASYA2f8wNWFiMWX//8OHM0LDrTDOtsO4w63Cu///SGVsbG8sIHdvcmxkIQ)

**Explanation:**

Uses the legacy version of 05AB1E because it can zip/transpose on list of strings, whereas the new 05AB1E version requires a matrix of characters. This would be 10 bytes in the new version by replacing `B` with `в` and adding a `J` (join) before the `»`. If any amount of leading 0s is valid, this could be 9 bytes as well in the new version of 05AB1E with `Ç3BZ°+€¦»` or `Ç3BZj»ð0:`.

```python
Ç          # Convert the (implicit) input-string to a list of codepoint integers
 3B        # Convert each integer to a base-3 string
   í       # Reverse each string
     ζ     # Zip/transpose; swapping rows/columns,
    0      # using a 0 as trailing filler for unequal length rows
      ø    # Zip/transpose back
       í   # Reverse each string back
        »  # Join the strings with newline delimiter
           # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Java (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net/), 80 bytes

```java
s->s.chars().forEach(c->System.out.printf("%05d ",new Long(Long.toString(c,3))))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XU7BSsQwEL33K8YFIZU2COLFrr2I4EFPe/AgHsY07aammZJMKiL77THd3YsOzAzz3uO9GXHBeuw@k5lm8gxjvmVkY2UfnWJDTl41hbIYArygcfBTAMzxwxoFgZHzWsh0MGVO7NgbN7y9A/ohlEcpwAO5ECfttye2hR7uU6jbINUefRCl7Mk/otoLVbe778B6khRZzlnNvdhcXt92sKmc/oJncoNYh2Q6uQlV3ZS5UnPMyk4gFvTrA3D3541MSlRKzywyXDZn8H@gdeLMHYq1Dyk9aWupglfytrv4BQ)

- -4 bytes thanks to [swpalmer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/111175/swpalmer).

Comment: Use (deprecated) ```new Long(String)``` instead of ```Long.valueOf(String)``` to save 4 more bytes

Answer (score 0):

## APL, 21 Chars, 39 Bytes

```
{∊6↑¨,⌿⍕¨(5⍴3)⊤⎕UCS⍵}
```

`(5⍴3)⊤⎕UCS⍵` converts input to base 3 ASCII code in five digits.

`,⌿⍕¨` converts the digits to characters and joins them together.

`6↑¨` pads space in between (also results in a trailing space) and `∊` builds the final output.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AUoAtf9hcGwtZHlhbG9n//9m4oaQe@KIijbihpHCqCzijL/ijZXCqCg14o20MyniiqTijpVVQ1PijbV9//9mICdIZWxsbywgd29ybGQhJw)

Answer (score 0):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 35 bytes

```ruby
->s{s.bytes.map{"%05d"%_1.to_s(3)}}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kqDSpcsEiN9ulpSVpuhY3lXXtiquL9ZIqS1KL9XITC6qVVA1MU5RU4w31SvLjizWMNWtrIUq3FCi4RSt5pObk5OsolOcX5aQoKsVCpBYsgNAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [J-uby](https://github.com/cyoce/J-uby), 30 bytes

```
:bytes|:*&(~:to_s&3|:%&"%05d")
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m700K740qXLBIjfbpaUlaboW-6ySKktSi2ustNQ06qxK8uOL1YxrrFTVlFQNTFOUNCGKthQouEUreaTm5OTrKJTnF-WkKCrFQqQWLIDQAA)

### Explanation

```ruby
:bytes |        # Get bytes, then
:* & (          # map with...
  ~:to_s & 3 |  #   convert to base 3
  :% & "%05d"   #   format to 5 digits
)
```